# How to escape the angled brackets ("<", ">") in a code block?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering, code-block

Writing a question including a C code in a `<pre><code>` block, I found out that in my `#include` lines the header names are not displayed when using the standard `<name.h>` convention. Instead, I had to use quotes `"name.h"` to make it appear. Apparently, the renderer treats these as tags, and I could not find a way to escape them. So, what is the method for doing it?

Comment: You don't have to wrap them in <pre><code> blocks yourself. Just use standard markdown formatting. Doing this should have your includes appear just fine.

Comment: Bart - if by "standard" you mean four spaces, please see my reply to @blahdiblah.

Comment: Yep, 4 space indentation. Ctrl-k. Simple as that.

Comment: Since then: [CommonMark and code fences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The standard way of including code is by indenting it all with four spaces:

```
like so
```

(literal text: "    like so")

Or, for inline blocks, surrounding it with backticks `like so` (literal text: "`like so`").

As you've seen, using `<pre><code>` has unexpected limitations and also doesn't support nifty stuff like automatic code coloring.

That said, if you really want `<` and `>` you can get them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
<foo>
```

Comment: Sure, this is easy for short code pieces, but when you have a long block, it is tiring to add and/or remove all these spaces while still maintaining the original indentation/tabulation.

Comment: @ysap, select the code and hit `Ctrl + K` or use the code indent button on the formatting toolbar, looks like `{}`.  I suggest hitting the question mark button on the right side of the formatting toolbar for additional editing help.

Comment: @Charles - thanks. This is definitely the best way to do this. However, my past experience is that I went into troubles using this operation - probably my fault, but once I learned about that <pre><code> feature, I decided that this must be the best way, as the code does not need any change to be displayed as code... apparently, the `#include` directive proved that even this has its own limitations.

Comment: The `&lt;` / `&gt;` solution is also useful if you are in a blockquote rather than a code block.