# We're switching to CommonMark

Tags: discussion, status-completed, markdown, announcements, commonmark

I’m Ham and I’m a developer on the *Teams* team here at Stack Overflow. Over the past few months, I’ve been heads down working on the way we turn Markdown into HTML when writing and editing posts across the network. I’d love to share what I’ve come up with.

*In a nutshell*: We're planning to use [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) for all posts across the network moving forward. To do so, we switch to CommonMark-compliant Markdown renderers on the client and the server side. We have to make sure that all existing posts work with the new renderers so we will run a big migration across the network that will convert existing posts to use the new CommonMark format. Writing, editing and reading posts should look and feel mostly the same after the change.

As of June 20, 2020, all sites are on CommonMark now. For individual sites, [see the migration schedule here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#348750).

---

We’re using Markdown throughout the Stack Exchange network. Markdown was one of the [early technology bets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/10/15/markdown-one-year-later/) when Jeff and Joel started out building Stack Overflow. If you write a question, an answer or a comment anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, you’re going to write it in Markdown.

Over the years, Markdown has become a common way of writing content in online communities. It has become a wild success and even got a [formalized specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/) with CommonMark.

Stack Exchange’s way of handling user-created Markdown today is largely the same as it was when we started. We’re using our own, home-grown Markdown parsers and renderers on the [client](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) and [server](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) side. Both of these implementations have proven to be a solid foundation and received a lot of tweaks over the years.

However, they come with their own quirks. Being created before there was a CommonMark spec they show some non-spec-compliant behavior. They’re using regular expressions for transforming Markdown into HTML (I’ll leave it to your imagination how much sweat and tears this has cost us over the years) which is perfectly doable but makes maintaining and adding new features to our Markdown parsers extra hard.

### The idea

We think it’s time to move forward. [You’ve asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957/) if we’re ever going to adopt CommonMark on the Stack Exchange network a few years back, [balpha ran the numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258587/507720), and while he found out that it wasn’t impossible, it didn’t seem to be easy peasy, either. With some of the past and upcoming changes, we think that now’s a great time to tackle this challenge and to migrate all network posts over to CommonMark. This includes:

- Changing the Markdown renderer on the client side
- Changing the Markdown renderer on the server side
- Automatically editing and re-rendering all posts across the network that are not CommonMark-compliant

To give you a better feeling for the changes under the hood: When you write a post on the Stack Exchange network, you write it in Markdown. On the client side, you see a preview of your post as you’re writing it. This preview is created by our client-side Markdown renderer. It takes the Markdown you write, transforms it into HTML and shows you a preview of what your post will look like.

Once you save your post, we send your Markdown over to our servers where the same Markdown-to-HTML conversion takes place, again (you can’t trust user input, so we don’t blindly accept the HTML generated on the client side).

### Our plan

We will migrate sites across the network to CommonMark site by site over the next couple of weeks. We plan to start with Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow on Wednesday, June 3rd 2020.

I’ve prepared a feature that will swap out our current, home-grown Markdown renderers with well-tested open-source implementations that adhere to the CommonMark specification. For the curious: this means we’re replacing [PageDown](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) with [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) on the client side and [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) with [markdig](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig) on the server side.

Once we enable that feature, new and edited posts will automatically be rendered with those new renderers. Most likely, you won’t even notice a difference when looking at posts.

With the new renderers in place, we’re going to move all existing posts across the network over to CommonMark. For the vast majority of the posts across the network (80% and up), this means nothing will change. Most of the posts on our network have been written in a way that is completely compliant to the CommonMark specification already, yay! If we convert this Markdown to HTML using a new renderer, the results will be exactly the same.

Then there are those posts that are written in a Markdown flavor that was cool for our current renderers but isn’t what CommonMark would expect. [Balpha’s analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258587/507720) is giving you more details on that. We’re talking about `##headlines` without spaces after the hashes and other minor oversights. For these posts, we’ve built a tool that automatically fixes these well-known issues by changing a post’s Markdown source directly and re-rendering the HTML of the post in question. When we change a post’s Markdown automatically, this will end up looking like a regular edit but we’re making sure that this won’t bump posts to the top.

So now we’ve got about 80% of our posts that are already good to go. With the auto-fixing utility we estimate that we’re going to land at over 96% of all network posts being rendered completely identical after migrating to CommonMark and using the new renderers. This leaves us with a few percents of posts that end up looking differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderers.

### What you can expect

We avoid breaking existing posts by erring on the side of safety. If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) we won’t automatically re-render the post and put it up for investigation first. This way we can be sure that all changes are safe.

I’ve played around with our data to get a feeling for the posts that will be rendered slightly different after using the new renderers. I found out that the differences fall into three buckets:

1. **False positives:** the HTML markup changed slightly but doesn’t change semantics or presentation of the post
2. **Improvements:** things where the CommonMark specification fixes some oversights in our current Markdown flavor
3. **Actual issues:** things that we didn’t anticipate and need to fix

The "actual issues" category should be a tiny fraction but I won’t naively assume that they won’t happen. There will be some changes caused by the new Markdown renderer that we need to investigate because they will cause posts to look different than before in one way or another. We can’t foresee all edge cases that this change will introduce so we will surface all posts that look different when rendered with the new Markdown renderer, review them and if necessary fix them.

Ultimately, we hope to make this transition as smooth and frictionless as possible. We don’t want to break (and manually fix!) thousands of posts. We don’t want to mess with your writing experience. At the same time, I know that we won’t get this feature perfect from the get-go, so I need to ask for your patience and understanding.

As you write new posts after we’ve made the switch to the new CommonMark renderers, you will have the exact same writing experience as before. The preview will show you what your post will look like and once you save your post, it should appear just as you saw it in the preview. *If you notice any differences between preview and saved post, please let us know!*

Things might get funky when you're editing a post that renders differently with the new CommonMark renderer. Again, if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration. This way, all posts continue to look the same when being viewed. However, once someone comes in and edits it, it will be rendered using the new CommonMark renderer and this might cause the post to look slightly different than what we had before. This will only be a small fraction of all of our posts, and of that small fraction a smaller fraction will actually be edited moving forward. However, it's important to keep in mind that editing old posts has a slight chance that you run into differences between our old and our new markdown renderers.

---

### Frequently Asked Questions

#### When is this going to happen?

The new CommonMark renderers are being merged into master within the next few days. They’re hidden behind a feature flag, so they won’t do any harm until we flip the switch.

We will migrate sites across the network site-by-site over the course of the next couple of weeks. We will start with Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow on Wednesday, June 3rd, 2020 (assuming everything goes well and we don't discover a major blocker until then). Since we can't exactly predict what kind of dragons we'll encounter along the way, plans might change slightly. I'll post a plan for sites and their switchover dates as an answer to this question and will keep it updated as we go.

Every site is different and we need to learn as we go. Most sites can be migrated within a few hours. For our biggest network sites, changing all posts to CommonMark will probably take up to 4 days. Keep an eye on the schedule I'll post to see how we're doing.

#### Why are we migrating to CommonMark?

In the past, changes to our Markdown renderers have been rather risky and high-effort. We needed to carefully evaluate if a change breaks anything for the millions of existing posts we have in place. By sticking to a well-defined specification like CommonMark, we can make sure that implementations that stick to this specification will work for us. If the specification gets extended, adopting changes will be easy and safe.

Another reason is that this reduces some of the maintenance burdens of our development teams. Instead of maintaining two distinct Markdown renderers, we can now pick something off the shelf and use that instead. With markdig and markdown-it we’ve found two reputable libraries that are beating our own implementations when it comes to performance and functionality. Both are great pieces of software that we're more than happy to use in our product.

#### Are there some changes to the way I can write Markdown in the future?

Yes, there will be a few changes to the set of supported Markdown on Stack Exchange. For the vast majority of your writing, you won’t see a difference at all. We’re doing our best to continue to allow most of the syntax you can use right now. We’re adopting the CommonMark standard, so everything that’s valid CommonMark will work on Stack Exchange moving forward ([here’s a short cheat sheet](https://commonmark.org/help/) for the curious).

At the same time, we want to take this opportunity to remove some quirks we’ve built during times where there was no such thing as a CommonMark standard. Some features in Stack Exchange’s current Markdown flavor have been built during a time where there was no standardized way of doing things. Now that we’re adopting CommonMark, we want to replace some of those homegrown features with standardized notation, a notation that you know from other places all around the web as well.

The most noticeable changes will be around lists, nested lists, headlines and blockquotes.

**Lists**:
When creating nested lists, you’ll need to indent your nested list items or paragraphs with the right amount of spaces. While one space was enough before, you’ll need to add a few more now, depending on your type of list.

To make a paragraph part of a list item it used to be enough to add one space in front of the paragraph

```
* this is a list item

 that goes on here
```

with CommonMark, the paragraph has to line up with the text of the parent, so we need a few more spaces here:

```
* this is a list item

  that goes on here
```

**Headlines**:
Moving forward, you have to add a space after the leading `#` characters.

```
#this was cool before
```

```
# this is what's cool now
```

**Blockquotes**:
Previously, empty lines between two lines marked as blockquotes would make one big blockquote. Moving forward, you'd get two distinct blockquotes this way, unless you start the empty line with a `>` character, too:

```
> old blockquotes  

> with multiple lines
```

```
> new blockquotes
> 
> with multiple lines
```

**Indented code block highlighting**:
Our biggest breaking change will be around indented code blocks and the possibility to declare the language to be used for syntax highlighting.

*In a nutshell:* If you want to declare the language for syntax highlighting in your code block, use the *code-fence* notation and not indented code blocks. You can still use indented code blocks, but declaring the preferred language explicitly for them is no longer supported moving forward.

Until now, you could do this to declare the language for an indented code block:

```
<!-- language: python -->

    def hello():
        print("Hello, World");
```

Moving forward, this style is considered deprecated. Ever since we’ve introduced code fences, you can explicitly declare the language of a code block using the code fence notation:

````
``` python
def hello():
    print("Hello, World");
```
````

This is the way the CommonMark standard is proposing and this is what other websites are doing, too. We know that you might have gotten used to using the old syntax featuring a `<!-- language: lang -->` comment. As we’re adopting new Markdown parsers, we want to avoid patching quirky behavior into those parsers when there’s an official, standards-compliant way of achieving the same goal that we can adopt with no extra effort. This style will continue to work for the time being, but is subject to removal in the future, at which point posts using it will no longer recognize it.

Note that setting the syntax highlighting language based on the tags you’ve associated with your post will continue to work. [Here’s a full overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) of the current behavior of our syntax highlighting if you need a refresh. We’re going to update that post as we move forward.

#### What happens to SE-specific syntax elements?

On the Stack Exchange network we support some syntax elements that are not part of the CommonMark standard. Things like *spoilers*, *MathJax*, *circuit diagrams*, *stack snippets*, etc. are used on several network sites. We're going to continue to support all of those custom syntax elements even if they're not part of the official CommonMark specification.

#### Will this finally enable table support?

*Maybe*! Support for tables has been [discussed intensely in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables?noredirect=1&lq=1). There are many creative workarounds out there but never any official support for rendering tables. If other sites can pull this off, why can’t we?

One of the main reasons, the fact that our Markdown parsers and renderers didn’t support tables, is now no longer valid as we’ve switched to Markdig and Markdown-it. Both support parsing and rendering tables out of the box. Still, introducing table support is a change we don’t want to blindly stuff into this big migration.

Let’s get everything to work nicely with the official CommonMark specification first – and just to be clear, tables are not part of that spec. This change is massive; we need to see how this plays out and make sure this doesn’t introduce more than a few acceptable cosmetic issues across all our communities.

Once the dust has settled and we’re all comfortable with the new Markdown renderers under the hood, we can re-evaluate if the time is right to bring table support back to the (*drumroll*) table!

Comment: Then would the syntax of spoiler be changed?

Comment: Does this also mean [we're getting header IDs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89314/332043)?

Comment: Spoiler syntax is going to remain the same - although it's not part of the CommonMark specification.

Comment: Also, regular space-indented blocks will still work, right? Notably [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11881144/6296561) kinda relies on space-based intentation to display the code itself

Comment: @ZoeTheLockdownPrincess *"You can still use indented code blocks but can’t declare the preferred language explicitly moving forward."*

Comment: This migration won't enable header IDs. This migration is already a big thing so we don't want to conflate adding new features with running the migration itself. Both, markdown-it and markdig support header IDs via plugins so implementing this feature will now be easier than before - but it remains a different discussion.

Comment: Will the apps continue to work properly with rendering previews/posts?

Comment: @Laurel the apps likely don't render the HTML themselves, but rather it's done in the API level. If that's the case, apps won't need any change. But if the render is done in the app itself.... this is essentially the final straw and they'll have to shut them down. Waiting for official response.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance If I understood this post correctly, the rendered HTML is saved in the database along with the source markup for each post.

Comment: *If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) we won’t automatically re-render the post* - I'm just curious to know what tool do you use to determine whether a post renders differently?

Comment: I run the markdown through the old renderer, run the markdown through the new renderer, scrub both HTML versions with good ol' regular expressions and compare the two HTML strings. It's not sophisticated but gets the job done just fine and is fast enough to handle millions of posts in my lifetime. I hope to get a blog post out soon where I can share more insights.

Comment: What about RTL direction, currently [unsupported by CommonMark](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/explicit-rtl-indication-in-pure-markdown/286/22)?

Comment: Does this apply to user profiles, too?

Comment: What about code in lists (both use(d) indentation)? E.g. 8 spaces (or a minimum of 5 until now?) indent for code at the first level in a list. I presume they are independent of each other, with indent for a list taking precedence (and code fencing to be used for the code), but perhaps address it explicitly in the question?

Comment: [Oh boy, here we go again...](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168)

Comment: Hmm, I use multiple levels of nested list and blockquote, possibly containing code, **a lot**.  What sort of changes will be required for, say, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273914/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900664/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40732416/3744182)?  Will I get a notification if/when you automatically edit it, so I can check whether the post is still readable?

Comment: TL;DR. Is the reason for switch _really_ that nuanced it needs a post _that_ long?

Comment: It's about time.

Comment: Hopefully this puts a stick in the wheel of the screen scrapers out there.

Comment: This is going to break a lot of old posts unintentionally, isn't it?

Comment: @Mast Huh? If the displayed text of a post would get altered by the new Markdown engines, then its Markdown *will not* be updated, even if the difference is a single whitespace. It will continue to be displayed via its current HTML, which was created by the old Markdown engine. So its appearance will be unaltered. **However**, when someone attempts to edit such a post they will have to comply with the new Markdown rules. This *may* cause problems. Eg, someone edits a post to fix some minor thing but then discovers that they need to make major changes so that the post renders correctly.

Comment: Tables ASAP, PLEASE!

Comment: What about placeholders of the form `[...]`, such as tag (`[tag:discussion]` for [tag:discussion]) or site reference (`[scifi.se]` for [scifi.se])? Are those just modelled as links whose definition is invisible at the time of writing?

Comment: TL;DR: does this mean questions/answers written 1 or 5 years ago could be parsed differently in a few weeks, and the layout might be broken for old posts? Example: what happens to previous posts with `#Header` instead of `# Header`?

Comment: @Basj Simple things like `#Header` to `# Header` will be converted automatically.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes in this case it's easy, but for more complex cases, there could be minor bugs / corner cases here and there... Format conversion always introduces some sort of quirks...

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it! Why changing the Markdown parser for millions of past questions?

Comment: Because we can't reasonably support two different active markdown renderers without tripping eventually. There are good reasons to move forward outlined in the post - compatibility, user experience, ease of maintenance, simpler future feature development being some of them.

Comment: Lost me at the code highlighting changes. Not a fan of code fences :-(

Comment: This is good, in my opinion. It is absolutely true that Markdown is an incomplete spec, and some solid flavor needs to be used instead. My peronal favorite happens to be kramdown, but it's not a good choice to substitute for standard Markdown in most contexts. CommonMark sounds like a good selection.

Comment: Will ctrl-k still work the same for both inlines and code blocks?

Comment: I just learned that [YouTube embedding and spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark?cb=1#comment1166961_348750) are considered 'extra features'. Could it be possible (eventually, not as part of this change) to get a Mod page which lists all currently enabled vs available features for their site in question?

Comment: at least it gets rid of the edits where all people do is change the formatting style.

Comment: Please consider adding to your FAQ questions above "*How do I download all my posts as they are right now?*"  for those people concerned that many of their site-specific answers might break. (likely a link to an answer elsewhere on site would do for an answer to that question) --- [While I think this is broadly a very good thing, a few more days of warning might have been handy]

Comment: For anyone who wants tables, you can use this tool for now: http://marklodato.github.io/js-boxdrawing/ It lets you easily draw vertical and horizontal lines, intersections of those and so on with Unicode box drawing characters.

Comment: How will the changes in blockquote syntax interact with nested blockquotes (for instance, me asking a question quoting an NTSB report quoting someone else)?

Comment: @Sean You can nest blockquotes pretty much the same way you nested them before. Instead of using  `> ` you'd start each line of a nested blockquote with `>>` (or more characters if you want to nest even deeper).

Comment: Would it be possible to have Tab characters in code blocks etc? This is important for some languages.

Comment: @HamVocke: I meant more "what to use in the blank line separating two blockquotes with different nesting levels" - does the separating line take the number of arrows of the parent blockquote, or of the blockquote nested within?

Comment: @Sean here's an [interactive example](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3E%20a%20blockquote%20%20%0A%3E%20spanning%20multiple%20lines%0A%3E%0A%3E%20with%20an%20empty%20line%20even%0A%3E%20%3E%20and%20a%20nested%20block%20quote%0A%3E%20%3E%0A%3E%20%3E%20with%20an%20empty%20line%0A%0A%0A---%0A%0A%3E%20another%20blockquote%20%20%0A%3E%20spanning%20multiple%20lines%0A%3E%0A%3E%20with%20an%20empty%20line%0A%3E%20%3E%20and%20two%20separate%20nested%20block%20quotes%0A%3E%0A%3E%20%3E%20with%20an%20empty%20line) that might answer your question.

Comment: @Robotnik possibly outdated and not complete (no list for spoiler block), but [What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/241919)

Comment: @Robotnik Spoiler blocks aren't an extra feature technically. They are available to every site, but (1) not advertized in the edit toolbar (fortunately!) and (2) only used rarely on most sites (if at all).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. YouTube embedding is, however, but it's also included in that list, so that might not be outdated at all.

Comment: `They’re using regular expressions for transforming Markdown into HTML (I’ll leave it to your imagination how much sweat and tears this has cost us over the years)...` I'd guess a lot.  Like most computing problems, this problem was solved back in the 1960's.  You should always use a formal state engine implementation for things that require a state engine like textual parsers, tokenizers, and the like, not hacks like regexes.  I blame Comp. Sci courses that today tend to teach Finite State Machines using theoretical approaches rather than practical implementations.

Comment: To clean up HTML as you mention in your post, you should be using a real HTML parser that uses a proper state engine under the hood like [TagFilter](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-web-scraper/blob/master/docs/tag_filter.md).  There are plenty of edge cases that a regex will miss.

Comment: Not sure if this is related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398089/markdown-help-page-syntax-seems-off

Comment: I remembered this old post from Jeff Atwood on why he choose to write the parser by hand and thought to share https://blog.codinghorror.com/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @bottlenecked I'd disagree with him there. Going one direction, the core business function you need to understand properly is rich text *entry* (i.e. frontend experience), not necessarily rich text sanitization. Going the other direction, using regexes rather than writing the parser from scratch is abdicating your responsibility. (It'd be like arguing that it's imperative that you write your 3D engine from scratch because you're a game designer.)

Comment: @Basj _"If it ain't broke, don't fix it!"_ Except that it _is_ broke(n). The code is not easy to maintain or make changes without breaking things. That counts as broken in the world of programming.

Comment: @FabianRöling There's also options like [AsciiFlow](http://asciiflow.com/).

Comment: #TIL (swidt?) that you're supposed to put a space after your heading hashmarks in Markdown! **#WHOKNEW?** (Not I. I did not know.) ...Don't tell me you're supposed to do it with code fences, too? I don't see myself ever getting used to writing '``` python', too much GFM for that to stick now.

Comment: So there will be a common renderer (or two renderers) across all sites. Does this mean extras like MathJax will also be supported across all sites? If not, why not?

Comment: How is this going to affect site performance? Right now, Stack Exchange and its Markdown rendering is one of the only remaining sites on the internet that's blazingly fast, without UX lag all over the place. Will this stay the same under the new renderer? Or will the new CommonMark implementation be built on ten layers of obscenely bloated JS frameworks that makes the browser slow to a crawl and makes the site unusable, like basically every other dynamic site has become?

Comment: Also, re: mathjax on all sites. Kill mathjax with fire and replace it with katex!

Comment: Are you sure [4 spaces are not required in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51941791/revisions) (instead of one now (and somewhat more later) as claimed in this question - near *"To make a paragraph part of a list item"*)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q With CommonMark, everything that's supposed to belong to a list item needs to be indented as far as the content of parent list item. [The spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#list-items) is kinda hard to read on this one but playing around with [this example](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=1.%20list%20item%20%20%0A%20%20%20three%20spaces%20needed%0A%0A*%20list%20item%20%20%0A%20%20two%20spaces) should show what I mean.

Comment: Nice, very good breakdown.

Comment: I don't think commonmark - or the desire to standardize markdown - gets the attention it deserves. I'm glad SO will be added to the supporters.

Comment: Will we ever get [highlighting within code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221268/highlighting-and-notating-part-of-a-line-in-a-code-block)?

Comment: Sounds good. Could we please have `Cmd H` **not** add `#`, because it means the browser can't be hidden if typing. On a related note, can we please have images get sized for Retina Display by default so we no longer need to [do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189638/306503) to make our posts look good? That would be excellent!

Comment: A+ for communication here.

Comment: Very good communication here, referencing past interactions with community, unlike the _other_ feature just released...

Comment: Is this newfangled mark thing the reason why Mathjax now appears too large to fit within the line causing almost one half of the letters to be truncated vertically making the mathjax unreadable?

Comment: Yay! Fantastic! I've updated the commonmark.org website to reflect this change!

Comment: Are you going to fix, will this change affect, this bug? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347187/139866

Comment: @Ham Were tag wiki's part of the migration?

Comment: @Braiam No, they weren't.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352506/bad-markdown-rendering-but-not-preview-when-using-guillemets/352511?noredirect=1#comment1178356_352511

Comment: Elaborate and respecful notification to members. I wish all changes to the StackOverflow tech stack were accompanied by similar advisories. It's not nice to learn from third parties on the web that StackOverflow uses such-and-such a technology for some aspect of its website.

Comment: Tab rendering bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403016/literal-tab-in-code-block-renders-as-four-spaces

Comment: Related: *[Feature Preview: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997)*

Answer (score 132):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> For these posts, we’ve built a tool that automatically fixes these well-known issues by changing a post’s Markdown source directly and re-rendering the HTML of the post in question. When we change a post’s Markdown automatically, this will end up looking like a regular edit but we’re making sure that this won’t bump posts to the top.

What will this do for posts which are currently licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 (or 2.5)? I see that previous edits of a similar kind (e.g. replacing HTTP links with HTTPS ones) trigger a license notification in the timeline ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1758/timeline)). I don't think edits like this should, especially not if the rendered content doesn't change.

@Yaakov says he's working on a fix, which is good news, but that fix needs to be applied retroactively, as can be seen e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/52/timeline):

[image]

Comment: You could read that version history as saying the edits made by Community are licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0... But the text on top, "Current License: CC BY-SA 3.0" is obviously wrong. And worse, if the last edit changes the license shown for the whole post, it'll change not only for automated modifications, but even if some other human user than the author makes some minor edit. It's not that rare for a user to write a substantial answer, which is then then copy-edited/clarified/expanded by another. Usually close to the original posting, sure, but sometimes much later.

Comment: This is key. I think it's already problematic that all edits, including minor edits and the automatic HTTP->HTTPS edits changed the license. This would affect even more posts than those, I would suspect. Handling the license needs to be thought through very carefully.

Comment: These edits will not cause a license change (I am working on a bunch of follow-up items for licensing, this will be included)

Comment: The edits cannot really cause a license change because they may be inserted in the timeline, and you don't want to jump to a higher CC version and then down again. It could become tricky if someone inserted a space after a leading # by him/herself and changed other things in an edit. Not sure, what the community bot wants to do in that case so enable earlier revisions to be in commonmark.

Comment: From what I understand, the fix encompasses things like the change to HTTPS, so it's going to be retroactive by default since *most* of the changes are years-old.

Comment: For the initial test sites, these edits will show up as being licensed. A fix in is being worked on right now, and will be retroactive when it goes up. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348883/51) for more information.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Retroactive fixes are not enough for license changes. This essentially means you can't trust the license displayed on Stack Exchange sites since you can't assume that the correct license is shown. Personally, I don't care because I don't reuse content in a commercial setting but others do that ...

Comment: [This appears to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348881/345161).

Answer (score 107):

### Migration Schedule

Here's an overview of the sites we're going to migrate, when we're planning to run the migration and the current status of that site. I'll keep it updated as we go. We might run into some issues along the way, so please understand that predicting an exact timeline is hard and we're going to adapt as we go.

#### Current Status

All sites have been migrated. CommonMark is used in our editor on all sites now. Thanks for looking out for and letting us know about issues you've found. This was a fun ride.

#### Done

<sup>*CommonMark* is active, posts have been migrated for these sites</sup>

1. *2020-06-03*: Meta Stack Exchange ✔
2. *2020-06-03*: Meta Stack Overflow ✔
3. *2020-06-04*: [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/physics-is-switching-to-commonmark-on-june-4) (Meta + Main) *initial run passed, another pass on 2020-06-11* ✔
4. *2020-06-04*: [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/were-switching-to-commonmark) (Meta + Main) ✔
5. *2020-06-10*: [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/the-commonmark-diary/8596#8596) Stack Exchange ✔
6. *2020-06-10*: Blender Stack Exchange ✔
7. *2020-06-10*: Code Review Stack Exchange ✔
8. *2020-06-10*: Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange ✔
9. *2020-06-10*: Chemistry Stack Exchange ✔
10. *2020-06-10*: Academia Stack Exchange ✔
11. *2020-06-11*: Server Fault ✔
12. *2020-06-11*: Stack Overflow en español ✔
13. *2020-06-11*: Unix & Linux Stack Exchange ✔
14. *2020-06-11*: Cross Validated ✔
15. *2020-06-11*: Stack Overflow em Português ✔
16. *2020-06-11*: Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange ✔
17. *2020-06-11*: Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange ✔
18. *2020-06-12*: Mathematics ✔
19. *2020-06-12*: Stack Overflow на русском ✔
20. *2020-06-12*: Super User ✔
21. *2020-06-12*: Ask Ubuntu ✔
22. *2020-06-15*: MathOverflow ✔
23. *2020-06-15*: English Language & Usage Stack Exchange ✔
24. *2020-06-15*: Ask Different ✔
25. *2020-06-15*: Salesforce Stack Exchange ✔
26. *2020-06-15*: WordPress Development Stack Exchange ✔
27. *2020-06-15*: Magento Stack Exchange ✔
28. *2020-06-15*: SharePoint Stack Exchange ✔
29. *2020-06-15*: Arqade ✔
30. *2020-06-15*: Database Administrators Stack Exchange ✔
31. *2020-06-15*: Drupal Answers ✔
32. *2020-06-16*: English Language Learners Stack Exchange ✔
33. *2020-06-16*: Mathematica Stack Exchange ✔
34. *2020-06-16*: Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange ✔
35. *2020-06-16*: Information Security Stack Exchange ✔
36. *2020-06-16*: Software Engineering Stack Exchange ✔
37. *2020-06-16*: Home Improvement Stack Exchange ✔
38. *2020-06-16*: Game Development Stack Exchange ✔
39. *2020-06-16*: Travel Stack Exchange ✔
40. *2020-06-16*: Role-playing Games Stack Exchange ✔
41. *2020-06-16*: Computer Science Stack Exchange ✔
42. *2020-06-16*: Webmasters Stack Exchange ✔
43. *2020-06-16*: Mi Yodeya ✔
44. *2020-06-16*: Graphic Design Stack Exchange ✔
45. *2020-06-16*: Web Applications Stack Exchange ✔
46. *2020-06-16*: Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange ✔
47. *2020-06-16*: Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange ✔
48. *2020-06-16*: User Experience Stack Exchange ✔
49. *2020-06-16*: Ethereum Stack Exchange ✔
50. *2020-06-16*: The Workplace Stack Exchange ✔
51. *2020-06-16*: Worldbuilding Stack Exchange ✔
52. *2020-06-16*: Data Science Stack Exchange ✔
53. *2020-06-16*: Biology Stack Exchange ✔
54. *2020-06-16*: Bitcoin Stack Exchange ✔
55. *2020-06-16*: Photography Stack Exchange ✔
56. *2020-06-16*: Seasoned Advice ✔
57. *2020-06-17*: スタック・オーバーフロー ✔
58. *2020-06-17*: Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange ✔
59. *2020-06-17*: Cryptography Stack Exchange ✔
60. *2020-06-17*: Japanese Language Stack Exchange ✔
61. *2020-06-17*: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange ✔
62. *2020-06-17*: Arduino Stack Exchange ✔
63. *2020-06-17*: Puzzling Stack Exchange ✔
64. *2020-06-17*: Signal Processing Stack Exchange ✔
65. *2020-06-17*: Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange ✔
66. *2020-06-17*: Emacs Stack Exchange ✔
67. *2020-06-17*: Aviation Stack Exchange ✔
68. *2020-06-17*: Русский язык ✔
69. *2020-06-17*: Law Stack Exchange ✔
70. *2020-06-17*: Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange ✔
71. *2020-06-17*: Bicycles Stack Exchange ✔
72. *2020-06-17*: Philosophy Stack Exchange ✔
73. *2020-06-17*: Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange ✔
74. *2020-06-17*: Network Engineering Stack Exchange ✔
75. *2020-06-17*: German Language Stack Exchange ✔
76. *2020-06-17*: Space Exploration Stack Exchange ✔
77. *2020-06-17*: ExpressionEngine® Answers ✔
78. *2020-06-17*: Craft CMS Stack Exchange ✔
79. *2020-06-17*: Christianity Stack Exchange ✔
80. *2020-06-17*: Hinduism Stack Exchange ✔
81. *2020-06-17*: CiviCRM Stack Exchange ✔
82. *2020-06-17*: Board & Card Games Stack Exchange ✔
83. *2020-06-17*: History Stack Exchange ✔
84. *2020-06-17*: Code Golf Stack Exchange ✔
85. *2020-06-17*: Anime & Manga Stack Exchange ✔
86. *2020-06-17*: Islam Stack Exchange ✔
87. *2020-06-17*: Politics Stack Exchange ✔
88. *2020-06-17*: Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange ✔
89. *2020-06-17*: French Language Stack Exchange ✔
90. *2020-06-17*: Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange ✔
91. *2020-06-17*: Economics Stack Exchange ✔
92. *2020-06-17*: Skeptics Stack Exchange ✔
93. *2020-06-17*: Writing Stack Exchange ✔
94. *2020-06-17*: Engineering Stack Exchange ✔
95. *2020-06-17*: Sound Design Stack Exchange ✔
96. *2020-06-17*: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange ✔
97. *2020-06-17*: Sitecore Stack Exchange ✔
98. *2020-06-17*: Astronomy Stack Exchange ✔
99. *2020-06-17*: Computational Science Stack Exchange ✔
100. *2020-06-17*: Physical Fitness Stack Exchange ✔
101. *2020-06-17*: Linguistics Stack Exchange ✔
102. *2020-06-17*: Chinese Language Stack Exchange ✔
103. *2020-06-17*: Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange ✔
104. *2020-06-17*: elementary OS Stack Exchange ✔
105. *2020-06-17*: Video Production Stack Exchange ✔
106. *2020-06-17*: Spanish Language Stack Exchange ✔
107. *2020-06-17*: Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange ✔
108. *2020-06-17*: Tridion Stack Exchange ✔
109. *2020-06-17*: Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange ✔
110. *2020-06-17*: Buddhism Stack Exchange ✔
111. *2020-06-17*: Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange ✔
112. *2020-06-17*: Pets Stack Exchange ✔
113. *2020-06-17*: Medical Sciences Stack Exchange ✔
114. *2020-06-17*: Joomla Stack Exchange ✔
115. *2020-06-17*: Parenting Stack Exchange ✔
116. *2020-06-17*: Expatriates Stack Exchange ✔
117. *2020-06-17*: Chess Stack Exchange ✔
118. *2020-06-18*: Homebrewing Stack Exchange ✔
119. *2020-06-18*: Project Management Stack Exchange ✔
120. *2020-06-18*: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange ✔
121. *2020-06-18*: Robotics Stack Exchange ✔
122. *2020-06-18*: Open Data Stack Exchange ✔
123. *2020-06-18*: Tor Stack Exchange ✔
124. *2020-06-18*: Earth Science Stack Exchange ✔
125. *2020-06-18*: Sports Stack Exchange ✔
126. *2020-06-18*: Russian Language Stack Exchange ✔
127. *2020-06-18*: Ask Patents ✔
128. *2020-06-18*: Monero Stack Exchange ✔
129. *2020-06-18*: Latin Language Stack Exchange ✔
130. *2020-06-18*: Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange ✔
131. *2020-06-18*: DevOps Stack Exchange ✔
132. *2020-06-18*: Windows Phone Stack Exchange ✔
133. *2020-06-18*: Literature Stack Exchange ✔
134. *2020-06-18*: Bricks ✔
135. *2020-06-18*: Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange ✔
136. *2020-06-18*: Amateur Radio Stack Exchange ✔
137. *2020-06-18*: 3D Printing Stack Exchange ✔
138. *2020-06-18*: Retrocomputing Stack Exchange ✔
139. *2020-06-18*: Italian Language Stack Exchange ✔
140. *2020-06-18*: Bioinformatics Stack Exchange ✔
141. *2020-06-18*: Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange ✔
142. *2020-06-18*: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange ✔
143. *2020-06-18*: Open Source Stack Exchange ✔
144. *2020-06-18*: Woodworking Stack Exchange ✔
145. *2020-06-18*: Computer Graphics Stack Exchange ✔
146. *2020-06-18*: History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange ✔
147. *2020-06-18*: Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange ✔
148. *2020-06-18*: Lifehacks Stack Exchange ✔
149. *2020-06-18*: Music Fans Stack Exchange ✔
150. *2020-06-18*: Stack Apps ✔
151. *2020-06-18*: EOS.IO Stack Exchange ✔
152. *2020-06-18*: Ukrainian Language Stack Exchange ✔
153. *2020-06-18*: Portuguese Language Stack Exchange ✔
154. *2020-06-18*: Poker Stack Exchange ✔
155. *2020-06-18*: Freelancing Stack Exchange ✔
156. *2020-06-18*: Martial Arts Stack Exchange ✔
157. *2020-06-18*: Sustainable Living Stack Exchange ✔
158. *2020-06-18*: Mythology & Folklore Stack Exchange ✔
159. *2020-06-18*: Internet of Things Stack Exchange ✔
160. *2020-06-18*: Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange ✔
161. *2020-06-18*: Esperanto Language Stack Exchange ✔
162. *2020-06-18*: Ebooks Stack Exchange ✔
163. *2020-06-18*: Korean Language Stack Exchange ✔
164. *2020-06-18*: Stellar Stack Exchange ✔
165. *2020-06-18*: Coffee Stack Exchange ✔
166. *2020-06-18*: Tezos Stack Exchange ✔
167. *2020-06-18*: Language Learning Stack Exchange ✔
168. *2020-06-18*: Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange ✔
169. *2020-06-18*: Operations Research Stack Exchange ✔
170. *2020-06-18*: Iota Stack Exchange ✔
171. *2020-06-18*: Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange ✔
172. *2020-06-18*: Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange ✔
173. *2020-06-18*: Community Building Stack Exchange ✔
174. *2020-06-18*: Constructed Languages Stack Exchange ✔
175. *2020-06-18*: Drones and Model Aircraft Stack Exchange ✔
176. *2020-06-18*: Materials Modeling Stack Exchange ✔
177. *2020-06-18*: [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) ✔
178. *2020-06-18*: Stack Overflow Teams ✔
179. *2020-06-20*: Stack Overflow ✔

Comment: Should we plan a date for all other sites ? as we would feel include inside the change as well that way :)

Comment: I'm going to add more dates to this schedule as we learn more and grow more confident over time. For starters I'm keeping this small because I don't want to over-promise without having a real idea for the first few batches we're going to run. I know that more clarity would be better but it's pretty hard to pull off. I expect us to be able to post a way larger schedule once we've migrated the first few sites.

Comment: @HamVocke It seems to me the least generally risky method would be to apply this change to smaller sites first, so any issues found would usually affect fewer posts, and then can be taken care of first before applying to the changes to larger sites later. Are there any particular reasons you can tell us about why the particular sites you show above have been chosen, and in the particular order you show them in?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Not trying to answer for Ham - but a note, both M&TV and Physics have integrations that may prove ... complicating factors - the YouTube embedding and MathJax.

Comment: We're trying to strike a good balance between size, risk, and impact. We want to learn on small sites first that include some unique features (mathjax, spoilers, video embedding). Then we want to move to the bigger sites in the network soon to get these changes into the hands of many users. I've picked the first few sites somewhat arbitrarily based on the idea of being small enough to allow fast feedback while using some of our special features. Hope this gives you rough idea of the general reasoning.

Comment: I do anticipate some confusion and room for bugs when different sites use different markdown dialects. Have migrations been tested and will they convert in both directions when needed?

Comment: We've built an automated rollback if things go horribly wrong. This will require undoing the entire migration post by post so it will be yet another intense calculation. If we can avoid a rollback, we'd love to avoid a rollback. I think we have to live with some level of confusion for the time being and make sure get all sites migrated soon :)

Comment: (Physics mod here) @HamVocke In case you're not already planning it, would you consider making a post on our meta site a day or two in advance to let people know to describe the change and look out for possible errors in post rendering? Sometimes it takes a little while for people to notice things on our meta site.

Comment: May we respectfully request that the "old" contents of a site don't get deleted until the denizens of that site have confirmed that nothing essential has changed?  When the tex.stackexchange site was last mass-changed, a significant proportion of our example code was trashed, with double-backslashes reduced to singles, rendering the code invalid, and many of us spent hundreds of hours repairing the damage manually.  There are still occasional instances of this carnage found from time to time.  We are shivering in our shoes.

Comment: The SE.Physics migration on 2020-06-04 seems notable since SE.Physics has MathJax (for TeX) enabled.

Comment: @barbarabeeton we won't delete anything. When changing a post to CommonMark we're creating a new revision of the existing post that can be rolled back manually or as a batch operation (if we really have to). Also, we're only creating those new revisions when we're confident that it's safe to do so.

Comment: @DavidZ good call, let me get something out to Physics and Movies & TV. I don't think we'll announce this for every single site but for the first few it's certainly reasonable to do so explicitly.

Comment: I would consider scheduling Puzzling prior to Movies because this would allow testing for spoilers isolated from video embedding

Comment: @HamVocke -- The last time it wasn't intentional, and we learned about the problem only when we started getting complaints that answers weren't working, in fact were causing compilations to crash.  Please let us know when this is scheduled (at least our moderators) so that results can be reviewed by TeX-knowledgeable users before activation.

Comment: @HamVocke as there is some disturbance around the licensing shown in the timeline would you consider holding off on switching over SO (and other technical sites with lots of code snippets) untill Yaakov has deployed the fix for the licensing issue mentioned in Glorfindel's answer? Just to avoid creating too much confusion.

Comment: I can see [ux.se] is a long way down the list, but don't forget BML. It might be good to annotate the list with particular issues you foresee (like MathJax and other oddities).

Comment: I see that TeX - LaTeX is scheduled for tomorrow.  Please be super-aware that TeX is **not** Mathjax.  (Many people equate them.)  I guess that tells me what I'll have to be doing tomorrow.  Fortunately, one of our active participants has been keeping track, and gave us advance warning.

Comment: You're doing Stack Overflow on a weekend?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I imagine that means someone will be in on the weekend to check it. Friday deployments are only bad if no one is in to use it/test it

Comment: Wow, that looks like a LOT of work, since each sub-site varies somewhat in its design and features. Do you guys ever wish Stack Exchange were just one site?

Comment: @Ham, please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581).

Comment: @Ham - was Arqade Meta done? I just found [this post's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13503/28182) header formatting was broken today.

Comment: @Robotnik Arqade Meta was done, yes. I can only assume that there was another slight difference in the resulting HTML when using the new renderer, so the migration erred on the side of caution and didn't auto-fix the headline formatting in that post.

Answer (score 53):

If you deprecate the use of `<!-- language: lang-html -->` in favor specifying the prettifier at the start of the code-fence, will you still support the overall syntax highlight hint for all code blocks?

`<!-- language-all: lang-none -->`

I have used that feature very occasionally so I doubt it has much impact if it can't be used anymore.

For putting things in perspective, this feature was used [2254 times](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1246508) in posts on Stack Overflow during the first 5 months of 2020. (Yes, I did try to run it for all posts but doing a full table scan over the `body` field isn't going  to complete within 2 minutes. I'm sure SE staff can run the query on the internal SEDE instance when needed).

Across all other sites (excluded Stack Overflow) this is the usage since 2017:

[image: stats showing 65 sites with max count of over 17,000 posts]
<sub>*click image for query*</sub>

Comment: I like being able to do this, but I’m not a fan of the syntax. If we could just mark the first codefence as “all-none” (or generally: “all-X”) and have it work the same, that would be a win. (Maybe give a warning for using the old syntax too.)

Comment: Yes, the `<!-- language-all: lang-something -->` syntax will continue to work. Same goes for inferring the syntax highlighting language from the tags attached to a question.

Comment: FWIW, SO is not necessarily representative WRT the use of this feature, as tag-based inference tends to work pretty well. Sites where tags are not (or cannot) be configured for this purpose may tend to make more use of this as a convenient way to turn on highlighting.

Comment: @Shog9 I've ran it across the other main-site databases for posts since 2017 and numbers are still low. But as this is confirmed to continue to work the whole point is moot.

Comment: Does `\`\`\` none` work now?

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky it works for me, yes. At least on MSO and MSE. If it doesn't work for you, please share the site where you are trying that.

Comment: @HamVocke Yet in your post you mention "Moving forward, this won’t work anymore.". How should we interpret this?

Comment: @Mast declaring the language for a specific indented code block is going away. With CommonMark's fenced code block notation we've got a perfect, standards-compliant replacement. Setting the overall language either by inferring it from tags or by declaring a `<!-- language-all -->` is going to stay for now. A new syntax highlighter might require us to revisit this in the future.

Comment: @HamVocke Ah, so setting it for the entire post the old style is still supported while for separate code-blocks only the new style is. We can work with that.

Comment: FWIW, I think your numbers are a little off, I've personally added that tag to multiple questions/answers on Code-Review [1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/239657/146810),[2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/232246/146810),[3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220565/146810). Is the query missing that site?

Comment: @Greedo now fixed, edited, new screenshots and links to new queries, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Tables: *[Feature Preview: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997)*

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q are you challenging me? ;)

Answer (score 35):

*Things might get funky when you're editing a post that renders differently with the new CommonMark renderer.*

If someone starts editing one of these posts that cannot be automatically updated, will there be some kind of notification that the editor should pay extra attention to the render preview because the edit may alter the appearance of the post? This can be particularly important when making small edits to large posts.

Comment: No, for now we won't show notifications. You're raising a valid point and we've discussed this idea before. We'd have to do an extra database lookup for each post we're going to show just to find out if there have been any issues while the vast majority of posts will be perfectly fine. We might have to reconsider this decision if the first migration runs show that there's a need for notifications. Until then we sure hope we get to a place where the differences are so trivial that we can just ignore showing a heads-up warning altogether.

Comment: Presumably if someone starts editing and runs into difficulties, they're responsible to either get it working or bail out, so we should not see mangled posts? You could set yourself a notification or special review queue for these special cases?

Comment: @Ham How about putting some kind of indicator in the Timeline / edit history that states that the post couldn't be automatically updated? OTOH, I guess that may not be very useful, since it'd be annoying to have to check the timeline before making an edit.

Comment: @Mr.Boy: The risk here is that you're reading a large post and see one paragraph or code block you want to improve.  You make that edit in the markdown, find that paragraph in the preview, and hit save.  You might not notice some subtle or even major breakage elsewhere in the post, if it's large and you weren't expecting any effect on areas you didn't change.  Not all users follow meta and will know to be aware of this.  Having a quote block split into two would be easy to miss; although not significant, it's still somewhat worse.  (Probably that specific thing would be auto-fixed, though.)

Comment: @PM2Ring It might be useful for searching, if only via SEDE, in order to find troublesome posts to fix manually (as time, effort and inclination allow).

Comment: This [just happened to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401190/did-header-markdown-change).

Answer (score 34):

Is this going to apply to chat as well? That has its own quirks in its implementation that are different from the main site (such as having to do `> quote` for a quote when `>quote` works on the main site). Is that going to change in any way?

Comment: No, this migration is not going to touch chat. It's only going to touch posts (questions and answers) across the network. Personally I think we should keep things consistent (and that includes chat and other places) but it's an entirely different can of worms.

Comment: @HamVocke - so it doesn't affect comments either?

Comment: Correct! Comments won't be affected.

Comment: Adding my voice here - now we're running 3 different, distinct dialects of markdown (Main, comments and chat) , and it would be *really* nice to have subsets of one running everywhere.

Comment: @Ham talking about can of worms, what will happen to Area 51? Will it be affected?

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance I don't know of anywhere on Area 51 that even use post Markdown. All the boxes there would use the watered-down comments Markdown system. The Area 51 meta site already runs off the same code as any other meta site.

Answer (score 34):

How will old revisions, in cases where they *would* trigger edits if they were current, be displayed when viewed?

To clarify my motivation for this question: As I understand it, each post that is currently not valid CommonMark will be updated by *one* non-bumping edit (which I presume will be shown as having been performed by the Community bot), translating the *latest* revision of the post from Stack Exchange's current Markdown dialect into CommonMark.

When an old (i.e., already non-current) version of a post, accessible through the post's revision history, contains Markdown that is incompatible with CommonMark, how will that version be rendered when a user accesses it? Will it still show the same HTML it once had?

And when diffs are viewed in the revision history--in the "inline" and "side-by-side" views--how will they appear? Will existing diffs (i.e., those between two successive revisions that already exist now) still render the same, no matter how old?

Comment: Your understanding is perfectly correct. In the revision history we calculate and diff a post's HTML on the fly based on the revision's markdown source. That means that after switching over to CommonMark, even revisions that predate the CommonMark migration will be rendered with the new CommonMark renderer. I know, that's less than stellar but it's all we can do if we don't want to keep the old renderer around forever.

Comment: @HamVocke - perhaps, once the switcheroo has been performed on all the sites, and everything that can go wrong has gone wrong (and subsequently been fixed) - consider running the updated migrator script on the earlier post revisions?

Comment: @Robotnik I think that would make it impossible to audit the changes. While the current way of updating simply makes a new revision, what you suggest will change the revisions themselves, leaving nothing to compare them with. That'd be awful IMO.

Comment: @HamVocke "That means that after switching over to CommonMark, even revisions that predate the CommonMark migration will be rendered with the new CommonMark renderer." In that case, please consider open-sourcing the client-side renderer so that it can be turned into an add-on/userscript for viewing old revisions.

Comment: @kelvin you can find the source code for our old client-side markdown renderer [on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Converter.js). Note that the published version is missing the latest significant feature addition, which is the ability to handle nested code blocks. I hope this can be helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 28):

## Block Quote migration [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I received strange "CommonMark migration" edits here:

1. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/344867/revisions
2. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/345953/revisions
3. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37844312/revisions

[image: diff]

Both quote whitespace formats appear to be valid CommonMark syntax, so I don't know why they were migrated in the first place.

The post-migration format is clearly worse as the quote marks no longer line up in plaintext.

> https://spec.commonmark.org/0.12/#block-quote-marker

Comment: Wow, awesome find! Turns out there's a bug in the markdown autofixer: When a line preceding a blockquote contains a hyphen, a subsequent blockquote will be indented. I've got a repro and will fix this now so we don't run into this for upcoming migrations. In those two cases, feel free to edit the markdown manually.

Comment: @HamVocke It's great that you've fixed this bug, but it is a bit concerning that the autofixer let that edit go through. That doesn't appear to be consistent with: *"If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) we won’t automatically re-render the post and put it up for investigation first."*

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand where your concern is coming from but that statement still holds true. _"Looks different"_ refers to the rendered HTML, not the Markdown version of a post. In the cases outline here the Markdown was changed but still resulted in equal HTML (because CommonMark allows some ambiguity).

Comment: @HamVocke Ah, I see. The new version looks the same as the previous version, and the HTML is the same. It's only the *Markdown* that has extra indentation.

Comment: It might be a good idea to also run a commonmark linter on the transformed results. A linter might be able to warn in cases the generated commonmark is legal, but weird.

Comment: @HamVocke FYI: added a bad/weird block quote edit that I found on Stack Overflow.

Comment: another: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/254472/revisions

Answer (score 27):

1. Do you have a list of all the 'well-known issues' that will be automatically converted? For example, I make heavy use of the `<!-- language: python -->` syntax. Will that be converted to code fences?
2. Will we be notified if one of our own post can't be converted, so that we can edit them ourselves? Or will it go to a dedicated queue?
3. Should we try to preemptively correct the Markdown content of our own posts if we suspect it might fail, or would it be preferable to wait until the automated migration?

Comment: I want to see *exact* list of what has changed.

Comment: 1. Language hints will **not** be converted to code fences. For a while our renderer will understand the old language hint syntax. This is going to change in the future so don't rely on it and start using code fences instead. 2. No notifications, no review queue for now. 3. I'd let the migration do the heavy lifting. No harm in correcting posts ahead of time but also no need to do that.

Comment: @HamVocke Language hints are processed by the migration, though, right? This is just about the transition period with the CMark renderer for new content and edits, yes?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking processing language hints is living outside of the renderer itself so they will be picked up still for a while. However, we'd like to take this as an opportunity to deprecate a hand-rolled solution that's been superseded by an official one and encourage everyone to move away from using old-fashioned language hints for new content because we'll get rid of them eventually.

Comment: @HamVocke does it mean that some long-forgotten posts using this feature will break after this "a while", when the renderer understands these comments, ends?

Comment: @Ruslan old posts are going to be just fine as we render the HTML of a post once and then serve that until someone changes a post again. Once language hints become unsupported, editing old posts that still use them means that you'd have to switch over to the new syntax.

Comment: "Language hints will not be converted to code fences." @HamVocke why not? Generally I've gone with the auto-detected language; if I override it, it's for a good reason.

Comment: @miken32 because it's tricky to get right. It's again a matter of trade-offs: How many users are using that feature vs. how long would it take to build an automated conversion vs. how big is the risk of introducing side-effects. And then there's the question whether everyone would be okay if we change their indented code blocks to fenced code blocks. To me risk and effort clearly outweighed the benefits.

Comment: @HamVocke "Language hints will not be converted to code fences" -- please reconsider that decision.  As I understand it, that would mean that all code which has been highlighted using the old language hints will (a) cease to be highlighted unless manually edited subsequently to add the new syntax; and (b) such manual edits will be changing every single line, which is (i) arduous, (ii) error-prone, and (iii) creates a diff for every single line of the code, making it ever harder to notice errors.  To me, this is a clear case for automated translation.

Comment: Further to the point about diffs -- I regularly edit other people's questions and answers to *add* language hints to existing code.  If they used indented code, I would add the SGML comment hints; if they used triple backticks, I would use that.  Either way, the edit diff I created was minimal, so everyone reviewing the edit could see at a glance that it was trivially correct.  The proposed change will mean that no one can add language hints to indented code blocks without *changing every line of the code*, which requires far more effort to do in the first place, and far more effort to review.

Comment: Not automatically migrating the indented code will likely ensure that few people will ever bother improving indented code by adding (or correcting) the syntax highlighting; and when they *do* make such improvements, it requires more effort from not only the person performing the edit, but from everyone who checks it.

Answer (score 23):

Do you also change the syntax highlighter at this occasion?

If I remember correctly, SE still uses Google Prettify, which [has been discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint). Support for more languages and new language versions would be great!

Comment: No, not at this time. Let's get this big and hairy migration out of the way first, then we'll have a good foundation for those kinds of changes :)

Comment: I vote for Pygments (Python)

Answer (score 20):

**Mathjax**

> Things like spoilers, MathJax, circuit diagrams, stack snippets, etc. are used on several network sites. We're going to continue to support all of those custom syntax elements even if they're not part of the official CommonMark specification.

Just to be clear, [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be severely crippled if MathJax support was damaged.  It is an essential for many sites.  [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) also use it and plenty of posts would be broken if the migration fails to support MathJax properly.

Is there a backup plan to undo the changes if the move to the new system (for obviously unforeseen reasons) should make using the new system not practical on sites that depend on the extras?  Or is going back not an option at all?

At the risk of insulting your IT department, is the existing site data being permanently backed up somewhere at some freeze date prior to the change?  If you have to translate existing questions to the new format there is (presumably) a higher risk this won't work well for sites with "extras" like MathJax and in the event changes (for who knows what reason) have to be undone, knowing the data was safe in its original form would be good.

Comment: The rendered html is stored in the database and so it is the original text. Also, the migration would be incremental rather than all of it at the same time.

Comment: We're only going to re-render a post if we figured out that it will look the same it looked before. Re-rendering is a matter of adding a new revision to the post history that includes the changes we're applying to the post's markdown. If this fails, we can always go and undo the latest revision. We've built a tool that does exactly that as a batch operation - if stuff's really broken we're going to run this automatic rollback and restore what was there before.

Comment: Worldbuilding ?

Comment: @TylerH Physics SE, Chemistry SE, Astronomy SE and Worldbuilding SE are all sites I use and which use MathJax.  Some Worldbuilding questions require science-based answers and equations are not uncommon there - a fair proportion of WB SE posts would be "broken" if Mathjax support went away.

Comment: @StephenG Sounds like there's a swathe of bad-fit questions for Worldbuilding then, but that's a subject for Worldbuilding Meta...

Comment: @TylerH I assure you that questions requiring real science are common on WB SE and not at all "bad fit".  Because they're almost all have a fictional component/framework to them those types of questions would be off-topic on the "real" physical science sites.  It is, for example, not unusual for Physics SE posts to be closed and recommended for WB SE (and the reverse also happens).

Comment: Add stats.SE to sites that use MathJax heavily...

Comment: RPG.SE does also see some significant amount of MathJax use, albeit mostly for formatting tables (though there is some use of it for statistics and the like relating to dice rolls/RPGs).

Comment: Crypto.SE uses MathJax a lot too, but the migration happened without a hitch in that respect (it seems).

Answer (score 19):

I seem to remember that CommonMark includes additional syntax beyond what SE supported so far, specifically bracketed enumeration, i.e. `1)`, in addition to dotted numbers for creating enumeration lists.

Is this true and **would this mean bracketed numbers will now be automatically turned into enumeration lists (ordered lists, or `<ol>`)?** This would be an amazing step forward with regards to Markdown's aspirations towards making formatting as intuitive as possible, since every second user who isn't aware of Markdown writes their numbered lists that way and it would be great if their posts suddenly worked automatically without requiring manual revision.

Previously requested here:
[Add parenthesis as an accepted Markdown ordered list delimiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/add-parenthesis-as-an-accepted-markdown-ordered-list-delimiter)

Comment: You're right, this is one of those places where CommonMark will bring extended functionality to our markdown syntax. After switching over, `1)`-style enumerations will automatically be transformed into ordered lists

Comment: @HamVocke: But only for new and edited posts, as you won’t automatically update the cache for those posts where there is a positive change – right?

Comment: Correct! Even though I'd consider this to be an improvement, our safeguards prevent us from automatically updating posts that would apply here. New posts and edits, however, get all the new commonmark goodness.

Comment: I have always thought it was a way to avoid it being formatted as a regular Markdown list (that is, some users go out of their way to control how the rendered result looks).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Another advantage of this finally getting fixed and this loophole for eschewing markdown getting closed.

Comment: @HamVocke There's probably a sizable corpus of old posts with `1)`-style lists. If I understand correctly, these won't be migrated automatically, and would need to be checked manually?

Comment: @E.P.: Correct. Unless the post includes one of the "changes to the way [you] can write markdown" listed in the original post (e.g. the stuff mentioned for lists, blockquotes, code block highlighting), it won't be re-rendered if it's an existing post. The change would only be applied if the post was edited or a new post made.

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [markdown-preview](/questions/tagged/markdown-preview) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Abbr.SE shortcuts are parsed as domains in preview

When I write an abbreviated site name, such as rpg.se or meta.se, it's now being auto-parsed as a link **in the post preview only**. It points to that exact domain and not one of our domains, i.e. `http://rpg.se/` or `http://meta.se/`.

The same happens with meta.so, meta.rpg.se, etc.

Hit the "edit" button on this post to repro.

Comment: Looks like the preview renderer detects them as country-code TLDs. See [this formatting sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349029/241919) for more tests.

Comment: Confirmed, this is our new markdown renderer being too eager on auto-linking. I've got a fix out that will remove this behaviour and make auto-linking stricter. Going out later today.

Comment: @HamVocke This looks like it's been fixed to me! Meta Andrew T.'s formatting sandbox post is handled correctly too. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 15):

### What was broken that needed fixing?

I apologize if I come off as ungracious, as you spent a lot of time working on this, but what was it that required fixing?

Seriously.  I've had very few problems using this interface.  What pressing need does this serve?

This question is based on a lot of years of experience of being immersed in "change for the sake of change" where in the end no value was accrued.

How will I see value added from this change?

---

I am adding in the comment response that answers my concern, since comments are ephemeral and I'd like to ensure that the value added explanation remains:

(From @[HamVocke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark/348909?noredirect=1#comment1167595_348909), thank you)

> With this switch, we get: A consistent user experience that aligns
> with what users know from other websites, predictable formatting,
> reduced maintenance burden on our software engineers, reduced risk
> when changing markdown formatting in the future, a stable foundation
> to build future feature enhancements around formatting and editing.
> There's value to our end users and there's a lot to win for our
> engineering teams in the form of massively reduced tech debt.

Comment: With this switch, we get: A consistent user experience that aligns with what users know from other websites, predictable formatting, reduced maintenance burden on our software engineers, reduced risk when changing markdown formatting in the future, a stable foundation to build future feature enhancements around formatting and editing. There's value to our end users and there's a lot to win for our engineering teams in the form of massively reduced tech debt.

Comment: I upvoted because the question was the same one I had in my head but was too afraid to ask for not wanting to appear foolish or incredibly naive. It led to a *good* comment, too. A comment that was easier to wrap my non-nerd head around.

Comment: @HamVocke Thank you for that comment.

Comment: @ham In other words: There is **no** value for end users whatsoever. Indeed, you are investing effort in making sure that there is no observable change at all. You can expect your readers to be developers, that are perfectly capable of understanding, that a change sometimes doesn't deliver any value, but rather enables future change that can ultimately deliver value. This is not the change that does, so there's not need to sell it as such.

Comment: @Tim Switching to a common standard most certainly *does* have value for end users, in that they do not have to learn so many similar but confusingly incompatible formatting rules for every site on the internet that uses Markdown.

Comment: @emi There's no value in *one* site switching to CommonMark. If *everyone* did, you might have a point, but even then, the switch needs to be as invisible as possible to be successful. There is no value for users in a change that's not observable (modulo some corner cases). Contrast that with Stack Exchange switching to, say, GitHub Flavored Markdown. Now *that* would deliver actual value. I mean, we've been asking for tables for almost as long as Stack Overflow existed. GFM has a [formal specification](https://github.github.com/gfm/), too.

Comment: @Tim Since GFM is in fact an extension of CommonMark, you just proved my point.

Comment: @emi I'm not sure which point you were trying to prove. If I have supported that, consider it an accident. Exchanging one Markdown renderer for another functionally equivalent Markdown renderer doesn't deliver value to its users. It's a change that's purely internal to the site, and - if all goes well - without any observable change. The fact that this enables delivering value at a later point in time doesn't magically turn this change into one that does. If you weren't made aware of this change, you wouldn't have noticed a thing. Does "no change" feel like "added value" to you?

Comment: @Tim ????? Where did you get the idea that that it’s “without any observable change”? The details of the syntax needed to write answers changed; that’s most certainly an observable change, and if I were not made aware of it, I would probably find out soon the hard way, and become confused.

Comment: @emi It's written all over the post, e.g.: *"For the vast majority of your writing, you won’t see a difference at all."* The changes you *might* observe are corner cases. In those rare cases, the switch to CommonMark is a bug fix. No matter how much you want this to be different, it really is just this mundane: The switch is an implementation detail, that doesn't itself deliver any value to users. Yet I concede that I was wrong about one thing: You cannot expect your readers to be developers after all.

Comment: Switching to a common and formalized standard (from a custom and probably proprietary mishmash of rules) will likely help long-term preservation of our content.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> You can still use indented code blocks but can’t declare the preferred language explicitly moving forward.

The [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#syntax-highlighting) is still mentioning this old method:

> To manually specify the language of an indented code block, insert an HTML comment like this before the block:
>
> ```
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
>
>      setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
> ```

It's probably hard to adjust this only for 'migrated' sites, but perhaps it's a good idea to remove it already for all sites, since with the code-fence notation (```` ```c# ````) we have a decent alternative?

Comment: Great point. This is somewhere on my long list of things to do but this might just be a good point in time to change our help center. I'll take a look :)

Comment: @HamVocke: Note [tkruse's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348902/335251) pointing out an issue with the description of blockquotes on that help page too.

Comment: @V2Blast yup, I've got a fix in review for both occasions. Will get both changes out soon.

Comment: @HamVocke It appears only the [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) pages were done, will the same be done for the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page (or is that a site moderator editable page)? Also do the statements after the example work, about specifiying a language for _all_ code blocks/removing the language, or do they need updated as well?

Comment: @Nick great catch. The help centre pages are mod editable. While I have permissions to edit I'd rather not mess with our mods' privileges and have them do it instead. The only thing I see that should be changed is mentioning the `<!-- language: lang-* -->` examples and replacing them with code fence notation.

Comment: @HamVocke mods can only edit [one page](/help/on-topic) and a few snippets in the Help Center itself and the Tour.

Comment: @Glorfindel dang, I had no idea. Alright, I went ahead and fixed the help center myself to make it consistent with our editing-help pages :)

Comment: We mods are happy to have privileges to edit more pages, if you want to fix that little bug right up while you're at it, @Ham ;-)

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Since the update to CommonMark, it's much harder to link to URLs with a `)` in them. Consider this link to the Stack Exchange API documentation:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=349185&filter=!)rTkraPYPefwELKox66q&site=meta&run=true
```

If I try to [link][1] to it as I used to, with a reference at the end of the post, this doesn't work anymore. (This answer already proves it.)

There *is* a workaround, a good old HTML anchor element:

```html
<a href="https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=349185&filter=!)rTkraPYPefwELKox66q&site=meta&run=true">this link</a>
```

produces [this link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=349185&filter=!)rTkraPYPefwELKox66q&site=meta&run=true). I guess using `%29` would work too.

[1]: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=349185&filter=!)rTkraPYPefwELKox66q&site=meta&run=true

Comment: It looks like the editing script doesn't touch these posts, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306515/295232; that's a good sign.

Comment: I'd argue [tag:status-bydesign] due to [the CommonMark's spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#link-destination): "*A link destination consists of either [...] and includes parentheses only if (a) they are backslash-escaped or (b) they are part of a balanced pair of unescaped parentheses. [...]*" and some more examples for inline link (489, 492-496).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. perhaps, but then it would be nice if the Community user would fix all those instances. Otherwise a lot of links are guaranteed to break...

Comment: This looks like a trivial fix when looking at link references (using `[link][1]` syntax), just find brackets and percent-encode them. When using the plain link syntax (`[link](reference)`) it's much harder as you can't reliably tell where a closing bracket is part of the URL and where it's supposed to close the link reference. Auto-fixing link references as part of the migration looks doable, auto-fixing plain links sounds like a huge rabbit hole to me. I can offer to try and fix the former but I'm pessimistic about the latter.

Comment: @HamVocke thanks! Such links have (AFAIK) never worked with plain link syntax, I think you can ignore those cases.

Answer (score 12):

What about **mobile** support?

I understand that the existing apps are no longer maintained, but it seems that plenty of people are still using them, whether or not that is a good idea.

My assumption: when the client side renderer changes, that will render all existing (no longer supported) mobile apps will be really broken and unusable after this change?

(Not a complaint, just a request for clarification.)

Comment: Are you asking about when you create or edit a post on the mobile apps or when you view them? For viewing posts - we store rendered markdown in the DB which allows us to skip rendering markdown on every request. Mobile uses the rendered HTML; it doesn't render the markdown itself. For editing/creation - we're discussing internally the best way forward here

Comment: I was mainly thinking about viewing, but sure, people who are still using the app(s) might be using them for creating/editing content, too.

Comment: I've just done a quick analysis on the number of create or edit actions on Stack Overflow over the last 7 days. Actions from our mobile apps account for 0.3% of creation events and 0.6% of edit events. We need to determine how many of those would have had markdown that resulted in different HTML but I think it's likely we won't be doing anything to address differences here - as you mention the mobile apps are [no longer maintained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385622/871146) and we're not in a position to ship a new build. As noted before _rendering_ will continue to function w/o issue!

Comment: Thank you, that is really excellent work from your side. I like that "data based" approach!

Comment: There are three parts to this: 1) viewing posts on the site (ones made before and after the change), 2) using the in-app markdown editor, and 3) previewing posts/edits.  With regards to 1, I don't expect breakage to occur, but it _could_ happen if the CommonMark generated HTML differs enough to break the CSS.  In this case, the page would just look ugly. With regards to 2, I don't expect any major issues since all the toolbar buttons should produce valid CommonMark. There might be point where a button transforms existing CommonMark incorrectly, that risk has existed since we added code fences.

Comment: With regards to 3, the iPhone and Android phone apps should be fine, as previews are done through API calls and server rendering.  Any post you preview in that way should come out exactly as it looked in the preview.  The iPad and (I believe) Android tablet apps use PageDown to render Markdown previews in realtime.  These previews now risk being inaccurate when a user hits a Markdown/CommonMark difference.  Again, this is an issue that exists today with code fences.  If you go to the app today and preview a question with code fences and it looks fine, you shouldn't see a regression.

Answer (score 12):

> For these posts, we’ve built a tool that automatically fixes these well-known issues by changing a post’s Markdown source directly and re-rendering the HTML of the post in question. When we change a post’s Markdown automatically, this will end up looking like a regular edit but we’re making sure that this won’t bump posts to the top.

For users who are curious about how these edits look like: visit the profile of the Community user (ID -1) on the site, and navigate to 'all actions' → 'revisions'. E.g. [here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works, as access to the Community user's activity pages was removed sometime [after 2022-12-07](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384482/271271), but prior to me posting this comment on 2023-12-28. IIRC, the removal of this access was announced by SE in another MSE question, but my moderate attempt to find the announcement wasn't successful.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [low-quality-post](/questions/tagged/low-quality-post)

#### The Community edits trigger post quality evaluation

Code Golf is currently seeing a [flood of pending reviews](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats). This is probably because many (good) answers on this site look like low quality, but had been approved previously or predate the current rules for automatic judging of quality.

Now that Community is editing the posts, their questionable quality is needlessly brought forward, and drowns new posts that *actually* require review.

Comment: That's a valid concern and I didn't anticipate this one at all. The review queue logic is quite convoluted and I assumed I had taken all necessary precautions. Sorry for the mess it caused. We're discussing possible mitigations for the next migrations and are also discussing _if_ we can fix this for migrations that have already run. If you want  to take action in the meantime to get unblocked, basically all edits done by "Community" around `2020-06-16 9:00 UTC` are the ones triggered by the migration and could be declared "ok". Again, sorry for the mess.

Comment: @HamVocke I'd be happy to do the OK click-fest if you allow me more than 20 reviews per day. A dozen of our users have already hit the cap trying to clean up the mess.

Comment: The Code Golf community has now finally cleared it's low quality post review queue. On the bright side, this pointed out many old answers that should have been deleted (for reasons unrelated to their quality score) but slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center)

It looks like the Help Center articles (they're written in Markdown) need some love from the editing script as well. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) (this one was [just edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349276/new-post-lock-available-on-meta-sites-policy-lock/349282?noredirect=1#comment1168942_349282), and [edited again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349276/new-post-lock-available-on-meta-sites-policy-lock/349282?noredirect=1#comment1168951_349282) to correct for the migration, but it's logical to assume other pages will be affected too):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

When editing a post, click the "Code Sample" icon in the toolbar, the traditional indentation still remains inserted.

I think that more inexperienced users will use the toolbar, so I would like to switch to the method of inserting the "code-fence" (```` ``` ````).

[image]

Comment: I get where you're coming from but strictly speaking this button remains correct. We introduced fenced code blocks more than a year ago and while I personally favor them over indentation, indented or fenced code blocks are a matter of taste and both equally valid. There's no obvious "right" or "wrong" here so I'd argue we leave it as is _for now_.

Comment: @HamVocke but indented is less functional now because there is no way to specify syntax highlighting.  To me that would be a strong reason no prefer codefence via the button.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that is a fair point indeed.

Comment: I agree, as new users will simply use the button or use indentation, regardless of the language that it is supposed to be. Then it would be up to a reviewer to convert the code to the fencing before adding a language hint to the highlighter. Not nice. I've created [my own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349840/17606)(overlooked this one, sorry) with some additional remarks about the language hint & the HTML tags displayed in the buttons.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As noticed by user [musefan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/170531/musefan) in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349492/strikethrough-markdown-not-rendering-on-post-but-works-on-preview):

Using two tilde signs no longer renders as strike-through text, but does render like that in post preview.

~~Click edit to see this text in strikethrough in the edit preview~~

Comment: Ah yeah. That's due to a mismatch of the currently activated feature set between our client- and server-side renderers. We didn't support a `~~` syntax for strikethrough before so we shouldn't blindly switch _right now_. Strikethrough can still be achieved using `<del>` HTML tags for the time being. We can revisit if we make `~~` (and potentially others) part of the supported markdown formatting options once the dust of this migration has settled. I'll get a fix out to align client-side and server-side renderers' behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Bit of a minor issue, but as I was updating [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/377214), I noticed that the character sequence `\$` was rendering as "$", instead of as "\$" as it was before the migration to CommonMark. It seems that in order to render the backslash prior to the dollar sign, one has to now escape the backslash by typing it twice (i.e. as `\\`), whereas this wasn't necessary in the prior renderer.

It seems that any symbol after a backslash will result in the backslash no longer rendering, e.g. `\.`, `\@`, or `\=` all render as ".", "@", and "=", whereas they used to render as "\.", "\@", and "\=" respectively. (The same doesn't happen to numbers or letters.)

Can posts using these also please be fixed automatically by the migration script, if possible? (Note that those sequences within code markup will still render as before, and don't need to be fixed.)

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[preview](/questions/tagged/preview)

As I was typing another post today, I discovered another difference between the CommonMark renderer and the previous renderer: certain symbols after a URL (e.g. colons) used to be treated as not being part of the URL, but now they are treated as if they are. This seems to only affect the *preview*, and not the actual post.

Example:

```
As per our FAQ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di:
```

...used to render as:

> As per our FAQ [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di):

...but now renders in the preview as:

> As per our FAQ [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di):

...with the colon being part of the actual link (as you can tell from the tooltip, or from clicking or copying the link).

This only happens in the post editor *preview*; on the actual post, both are rendered the same, with the colon *not* being part of the link.

Can this issue with the preview please be fixed?

Comment: Seems to be fixed now for your `:` example.  `(` in URLs still breaks things in general, though, e.g. https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=div%20(r64&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKL=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_ZEN2=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_base=on consumes a `)` as part of the URL for `[foo](https://example.com/foo?bar=xyz(r64 )`, and the control-L link-at-the-bottom thing just plain doesn't work for it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not fixed. This issue is about the *editing preview*; it looks fine in the actual post.

Comment: Ahh, I see I didn't read carefully enough when looking for existing reports of a problem I found: [Editor preview shows links clickable, final rendered post doesn't, when surrounded by \[\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351191) might be semi-related.

Comment: The link now renders in the preview without the colon (rather than the colon being a part of the actual link). Still a bug, though.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It's possible to post empty posts by using HTML comments. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348983/332043). Note that this has been repro'd on sites with and without CommonMark (https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6925/revisions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398084/revisions - both links require 10k. Same basic idea though).

This is probably a regression - these types of posts used to be blocked before they were posted.

Comment: This sure does look like an issue. However, since we reproduced the issue on puzzling.SE, a site that's not yet migrated to CommonMark, we can be certain that the CommonMark migration won't be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Related (MSE): *[Scan posts for nonsensical HTML comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349113/scan-posts-for-nonsensical-html-comments)*

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Code highlighting in the preview during post editing does not seem to work anymore. Upon publishing, it still works fine. To reproduce, just hit `edit` on this post and have a look at the preview..

```python
from __future__ import braces
```

This is especially irritating because at least I can never remember on which sites I need to write ```` ```python ````, on which I need ```` ```lang-python ```` and on which both work (or do I need a space or ...). Without a live preview I have to guess and maybe re-edit (as I did in this question).

Comment: Good catch. I've reproduced the bug and got a fix out for review. I could've sworn that I had tested this behavior but it looks like I missed it.

Comment: A fix is going out right now, revision `2020.6.12.37041`

Comment: @HamVocke I'm not sure what "right now" means, but this bug persists. Where can I check the status of that revision?

Comment: you can see the currently deployed revision in the footer at the bottom right of a page (where it says `rev XYZ`). Syntax highlighting in preview works for me but I acknowledge that sometimes it takes a while and some more typing to kick in (as was before switching to CommonMark). Looks like something we could tweak on another day.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [Stack Overflow editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) links to the original John Gruber markdown specs in the "Need more detail?" section.

Shouldn't it point to the CommonMark specs?

Answer (score 7):

Did I understand correctly that you will be fixing the compatibility issues listed *automatically*, like more indentation necessary for list paragraphs, quote markup before empty lines, missing spaces before headlines,...? It might very well be that the question covered that already under the general migration explanations, but I just want to make **super sure that you've covered this**. I would *not* want a load of misaligned paragraphs or multi-block quotes appearing all of a sudden in 10,000 existing posts.

Comment: Yes, the migration will fix compatibility issues in a post's Markdown automatically as good as we can. Chances are, there are some fixes that we haven't covered yet but most trivial issues will be fixed automatically. To reiterate: if we can't fix a post automatically and we'll discover that the new HTML would look differently, we will not touch this post at all.

Comment: @HamVocke, what does "not touch this post at all" mean here, exactly? that the source and rendered content would same as they were, and it will blow up then if anyone edits it, when the new parser processes the source? :)

Comment: @ilkkachu that's pretty spot on, yes. Whenever we find one of these posts, we'll save it so we can investigate what's going on. I expect that most of these occurrences will be trivial. The next person editing won't even notice that something's changed. For those cases where the post looks _fundamentally_ different, we'll add more automatic fixes and re-run the migration. It's a matter of trade-offs. We could put in the work and fix every single issue carefully or focus on the big ones, ignore the trivial ones and cause mild inconvenience _if_ someone edits a post moving forward.

Comment: @HamVocke: Thanks for the explanation! That makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Couple of questions:

1. Are you going to update the HTML (since it is cached) or just the raw Markdown code?
2. Are you also going to add an entry in the edit history, presumably saying that [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) made the change?

Comment: We will update the raw Markdown whenever it's safe to do so (i.e. the resulting HTML is equivalent to the old HTML). Technically this will rebake the HTML as well. We're storing the update as a new edit, triggered by the community user and without bumping the post itself.

Comment: @HamVocke: Will you do some sort of automated checking that the old HTML is equivalent to the new HTML? (And maybe communicate whatever cannot be fixed to moderators?) As a MathOverflow and math.stackexchange user, I'm somewhat worried about posts suddenly becoming unreadable and staying so for years because no one with edit rights takes notice.

Comment: @darij https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark/348755?noredirect=1#comment1166968_348752

Answer (score 7):

A small discrepancy between preview and post that I noticed today on SO:

Something like http://localhost:3000 gets previewed as a link, but in the post it's regular text.

For example right now when writing this post:
[image]

**EDIT:** In comments they do render as link by the way.

Comment: I reported a similar problem with links [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581).

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Tabs are not handled properly anymore, which makes it difficult to format CommonMark source code properly.

#### Example 1

Using a tab to indent contents of a list does not work.
It appears to be treated like one space.
This is in conflict with [the CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#tabs).
For example,

```
*——⇥test
———⇥
———⇥test
```

renders as:

> - test
>
>   test

while it should render as:

> - test
>
>   test

#### Example 2

Tabs in code environments are bluntly substituted by four spaces instead of making a four-space indentation.
For example,

```
———⇥*——⇥test
———⇥———⇥test
```

renders as:

> - test
>   test

while it should render as:

> - test
>   test

Comment: I agree, it looks like we're missing something here and the new behavior is slightly different than the old one. For clarity: We've always replaced tabs with spaces when converting Markdown to HTML, with CommonMark in place, we continue to do so. Let me see what's happening here that makes indentation different from the old renderer.

Comment: Got a fix out with the the latest revision (`2020.6.12.37042`) that should address the issues you describe. If you edit your post, you should be able to see the new behavior.

Comment: @HamVocke But there are often tabs in SO code blocks, how did they get there?

Answer (score 5):

## Multi-paragraph quote blocks within lists [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The automatic migration on Movies & TV omitted [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27014/49), either because it failed to convert it into an HTML that didn't change or because it didn't recognize it as a case that needs adaptation.

However, it clearly needs it since it has both multi-paragraph quote blocks and multi-paragraph bullet points and when trying to edit it, it looks like a mess needing manual fixing. The problem seems to be, though, that it has **multi-paragraph quote blocks *inside* a list**, so it doesn't seem to be able to introduce both the added indentation *and* the `>` quote marker on the same line.

Comment: You're right, the block quotes need an additional leading space to be properly indented as part of the parent list item. This is one of the weak spots for the autofixing mechanism. I'll try to tune it using this particular example but ultimately this might be one of the cases where we just have to deal with manual fixing since every tweak I introduce to the autofixer risks breaking other occasions that look similar but aren't quite the same.

Comment: @HamVocke That...would be more than unfortunate. I can't believe this being the only case of a multi-paragraph quote block inside a list, nor this being particularly hard to fix. Trying to solve the problem generally more than tuning it to this specific answer I brought up as just an example might be a better idea.

Comment: @HamVocke If this is not at all possible, though. *Please*, please consider sharing the list of posts that failed the HTML comparison and should definitely contain these cases. At least people would have a hint at which posts might need manual fixing then, especially when things get tuned to specific cases and it's left unclear what other possible edge cases might exist that haven't surfaced yet.

Comment: I understand that this is less than ideal. The migration script is designed in a way that it can be tweaked and re-run on a site to pick up some things that haven't been picked up before (in fact, I did exactly that this morning on this site). I'm keeping an eye out on the failure cases and so far the one you highlighted is one of the few more uncomfortable ones. I'm not trying to hide anything and am happy to share a list if I can reasonably do so. The thing that's holding me back is that the list I have consists of 95% false positives that are hard to weed out even after weeks of tweaking.

Comment: @HamVocke Okay. False positives as in different HTML code but still looking the same?

Comment: lots of papercuts, really. Visually equivalent but structurally different HTML in most cases, yes. Unfortunately it's pretty hard to weed out everything. I've spent the better part of the past few weeks trying and decides that ultimately we can't eliminate them all with reasonable effort.

Answer (score 5):

How is this going to affect site performance?

Right now, Stack Exchange and its Markdown rendering is one of the only remaining sites on the internet that's blazingly fast, without UX lag all over the place. Will this stay the same under the new renderer? Or will the new CommonMark implementation be built on ten layers of obscenely bloated JS frameworks that makes the browser slow to a crawl and makes the site unusable, like basically every other dynamic site has become?

Comment: Well, you wrote this answer using CommonMark, how did it feel?

Comment: @Spevacus: Excellent, exactly what I wanted to hear!

Comment: Given that posts are converted to HTML only upon creation/editing, I don't see how it *could* affect any random everyday page loads.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Loads are not the problem, editing is. To actually *use* this site you use the editor, writing questions and answers. Lots of dynamic sites with custom editing widgets have up to 1s latency for each keypress. Patreon has it and new Twitter had it at first but has mostly fixed it. Facebook kinda has it too but it stabilizes over time (JIT kicking in?) Others are not as extreme but still have serious usability problems from JS event handlers running on everything you input, so this absolutely was/is a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 5):

## User profile descriptions haven't been re-rendered with CommonMark, neither have they been migrated

Even on sites that have been migrated over to CommonMark, user profile descriptions haven't been migrated to use the new renderer, and prior user profile descriptions are still rendering as is.

I noticed this when editing my [my user profile](/users/377214), which has a heading that uses the now-no-longer-valid form of not having any space after the hash signs (i.e. `##heading`):

> [image: Heading that uses now-invalid markup still renders]

Here's a screenshot of my profile editor, to prove that that heading is the result of the now-invalid form above. (The preview is rendered with CommonMark, but this doesn't match the output in the above screenshot.)

> [image: Profile editor, which uses CommonMark renderer]

I initially thought that this was because user profiles hadn't been updated to use CommonMark, but when I saved my profile without making any new changes, it re-rendered with CommonMark, and the heading didn't show up correctly (as would be expected).

Are user profile descriptions going to be migrated to CommonMark just like posts, with them all being re-rendered and edited by the migration script, or will they remain as is?

And if they are to be retained as is, can there please be warning notices on the editor page to notify the user to check to see if their profile description would render the same? Saving the profile without making any changes to the description field (e.g. to just change something else, such as the username, location, etc.) will re-render it with CommonMark, potentially making it break unexpectedly if the bio uses now-unsupported markup. (I read the comments indicating that this would be difficult on posts because of having to detect issues, but this is much easier as the warning can just be applied to all profiles that haven't been edited since the site's transition.)

Comment: You're right, this migration _only_ tackles posts (i.e. questions and answers). Ultimately, we want to use CommonMark for tag wikis and user profiles too so we can get rid of the old Markdown renderer. We need to take careful steps, that's why tag wikis and user profiles are not included in this migration. We'll follow up with replacing the renderer properly for both at a later point.

Comment: @HamVocke As my answer states, on transitioned sites, user profiles are rendered with the CommonMark renderer *when the user edits any part of their profile* (not just the description). Is it possible that a warning can be shown on profiles that haven't been edited since the site's transition and whose about me isn't blank that they should check their description to see if it would render differently?

Comment: Sorry, early morning confusion here. You're right, the new renderer is already being used for edits in tag wikis and user profiles, but existing profiles aren't migrated. Showing a warning sounds like a possible solution. I'll have to do some digging to see if there are any dragons to be aware of.

Comment: @HamVocke as irony would have it, the tag wiki for [tag:markdown] is affected. I left it in its current state in case you want to investigate.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks! I've edited the description manually to make it commonmark compliant. It was an issue with mixing HTML and markdown. Unless we'd run a automated migration for tag wikis, there'll likely be more of those cases floating around.

Answer (score 5):

### Newline added between links listed in "[1]: link" format

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I'm honestly just wondering what happened to [one of my posts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/157140/revisions). Viewing [the source before the community bot edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/3e5529d2-53fa-4e99-bbde-9400767bea84/view-source) and [the source after that edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/b3c597a7-af9c-456b-a8ad-d07e2aa5fe3b/view-source) the only difference I can see is that a newline was added between two of the links. Did this happen because I (for reasons even I don't know) used [1], [1.5], and [2] for my links? (I used them in this post and nothing seems to have gone wrong)

I don't believe this really counts as a bug of any sort, but I am wondering what actually happened in this case; why did the bot add a newline in the middle of my links?

Comment: Yep, this is a case where the auto-fixer incorrectly made an edit. The resulting HTML is still the same which is why this edit got saved. The auto-fixer is inserting empty lines before link references at the end of the document if there's no empty line. Because of the `[1.5]` formatting, it didn't recognize that this line was a link reference in itself.

Comment: @HamVocke The link references can be any unique string which is explicitly called out in the help centre: _"The link definitions can appear anywhere in the document -- before or after the place where you use them. The link definition names [1] and [yahoo] can be any unique string, and are case-insensitive; [yahoo] is the same as [YAHOO]."_ Does this mean those `[yahoo]` ones will have this bug as well or is it solely a problem because of the `[1.5]`?

Comment: But then again, is this really a bug, as the resulting rendered page is not affected in any way?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I know. The assumption I made in the auto-fixer was overly simplified. I don't really think this is a problem beyond a slight annoyance. Only link references that include punctuation characters are affected.

Comment: @HamVocke Oh yeah I don't think it would need correcting, just wondering what would be affected by it. Good to know.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I just stumbled across [this *old* answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/5070/14934) on Money.SE.  It has two numbered points, with text in the middle. The text and the preview both have a `1.` and a `2.`, but on the main page it renders as two `1.`'s.  I don't know what it looked like before.

Main: [image: Main page]
Edit: [image: Edit]
Preview: [image: Preview]

Comment: That answer wasn't migrated so it is still rendering with SE's markdown at the moment I believe. At least that was my understanding of how it works, could be wrong.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Does that mean the double #1's is how it's always been, and CommonMark would clean it up once someone made an edit?  How can you tell whether an answer was migrated?

Comment: The timeline for the post (example [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/168943/timeline)) will show a Community edit with "Commonmark migration". Per my understanding, but I may be wrong, only migrated posts (and new ones) are now using CommonMark, everything else is still currently rendering with markdown. I could have completely misunderstood though and only "problem" posts aren't using CommonMark now.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a good idea to migrate the code-sample button (in the editing bar on top of the edited post) to use the fencing option if that's going to be the reasonable default. Some indication on how to change the language of the code block might be a good idea for new users, or they may stay unaware of that option.

Currently the description of the edit buttons list the way you can manually insert HTML, rather than Markdown. That may lead to posts with a mix of Markdown and HTML rendering. It certainly seems to void the principle at least surprise: hit a button that says it inserts `<ol>` or `<pre>` and then use a Markdown list or indent / fence instead. Personally I'd just leave it out: I can see what happens when I press the button. Less is more.

Comment: Already mentioned above: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349575.

Comment: Ah, right, and I tried to scan through all the answers first. There are quite a few of them so I must have skipped it. I'll leave it here for the other remarks.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> Again, if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration.

Is there a list of these posts available per stack (or queryable from SEDE), so that we can fix these manually?

Comment: No. During the migration we saved the IDs of all posts that couldn't be migrated in Redis so we can get a feeling for the overall shape of the migration failures. However, this data has a _bad_ signal to noise ratio, flagging lots of posts that aren't problematic after all. As much as I'd love to publicly share that data for people to go and investigate, I feel that this would rather be counter-productive and send everyone off on the wrong tracks.

Answer (score 4):

Why not leave the rendered HTML for old posts alone, as was done for previous updates to the Markdown renderer (iirc)?

Comment: They're rendering the new HTML to check for changes as compared with the old HTML, and discarding updates that change the output. So essentially they are leaving the rendered HTML alone. "...if we detected that a post would look [different] when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration."

Comment: Keeping html different from source is a time bomb, that will hit the next editor, who doesn’t expect to fix markdown differences

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> When we change a post’s Markdown automatically, this will end up looking like a regular edit but we’re making sure that this won’t bump posts to the top.

I've noticed several posts here on Meta that seem to have been bumped by the community user's "Commonmark migration" edit to an answer:

The 3rd revision to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256969/390409) for [Change "comment" to "critique or request clarification"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256967/change-comment-to-critique-or-request-clarification)
The 2nd revision to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299400/390409) for [SE site for architecture design questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299398/se-site-for-architecture-design-questions)
The 2nd revision to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348816/390409) for this recent question: [What did Yaakov do to this post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348806/what-did-yaakov-do-to-this-post)

It looks like the question *isn't* bumped (e.g. the first one was bumped by a spam answer), but the Community user *is* shown as the latest active user, with a timestamp belonging to another action that last bumped the post. Here are some screenshots for the second question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We're using the community user to create the new revision and deliberately suppress edit bumps. Looks like for all three posts listed here, there's been activity (other edits, deleted answers) during a similar time frame and that caused the activity bump? Totally plausible that I'm missing something here and please correct me if I'm wrong but to me it looks like everything's working as intended.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll leave the answer here in case anybody else sees this behavior and comes looking.

Comment: For the first one: looks like the spammer account getting nuked, the user will be shown as Community user instead.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps update the [PageDown](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) and [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) readmes with a link to this question?

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

There's a weird bug with HTML comments, where it collapses future paragraph breaks:

```
<!-- -->Paragraph A

Paragraph B
```

Paragraph A

Paragraph B

```
<!-- -->
Paragraph A

Paragraph B
```

Paragraph A

Paragraph B

Comment: This is one of the things where CommonMark is slightly different than our old renderer. Mixing HTML with Markdown is always a fun adventure (always has been) and in this case I'll argue that this works as designed. If you really have to write raw HTML in your CommonMark, make sure to not mix HTML and Markdown but to separate it with an appropriate amount of newlines. Otherwise, CommonMark will interpret everything as one big HTML block and ignore your Markdown.

Comment: For more details take a look at [this example](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3C!--%20--%3EParagraph%20A%0A%0AParagraph%20B%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C!--%20--%3E%0AParagraph%20A%0A%0AParagraph%20B) and check out the `AST` tab. You'll see  that in your first example `Paragraph A` is considered part of the HTML block, thus no paragraph node will be generated. For the second example, the HTML block stops after your closing comment and `Paragraph A` is detected as a paragraph according to regular Markdown.

Comment: Interesting. Not hard to work around in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Are tag wikis missed in the CommonMark migration?

Several tag wikis make use of headers and blockquotes, but no edits have been made by the Community User on tag wikis to change
`###This header` to `### This header` and to add `>` between consecutive blockquotes.

For example, see the tag wiki here for [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension). (Posts on Meta SE were migrated to CommonMark on 2020-06-03 as per the given [schedule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750).)

Comment: Yes, for now we're only migrating posts (i.e. questions and answers). When writing or editing a tag wiki, you'll use the new renderer but we're not migrating existing ones to the new format for now.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Would it be possible to use the occasion to throw in highlighting of specific code lines (as opposed to syntax highlighting) by providing the info in the [infostring](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#info-string)?

Something like:

````
```cs highlight=15
<code>
```
````

And then it would highlight the line 15 as if with a highlighter.

Or, for a more complex example,

````
```cs highlight="23-25, 31"
<code>
```
````

We do have a recurring problem of people trying to use `**` in codeblocks to highlight specific lines. In some languages it's easy to spot and edit out, in some other languages it may even look like a valid attempt at pointer manipulation, which confuses everyone.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Share links followed by a dot within Markdown syntax like italics (`*`) have the dot included in the link. Before the dot was not included.

```
*Read mode about this in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/218578.*
```

*Read mode about this in [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/218578.)*

---

Note that in the preview, the behaviour is still as before, the dot is not included in the link. What makes it easy to inadvertently post a broken link like the one above:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349244.

Comment: I also raised a similar problem [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I've seen that before posting. But it's slightly different, and mainly the other problem seems gone. Their *"used to render as"* and *"but now renders in the preview as"* sections are now identical.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Migrated questions show up in the Reopen queue like [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/32551) and [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/32691) because they "have been edited after they were closed".

Comment: At least you know which users to ban for voting to reopen now :)

Answer (score 4):

## Will underscore's styling role continue?

I just finished reading through commonmark.org's [help section](https://commonmark.org/help/) and I'm quite pleased with the rationale behind SE's decision and CommonMark's mission.

One caveat I often find, however, is the underscore used for italics, since it is so often used in file names as well. This would imply that file names must ***always*** be placed inside inline `code ticks`.

Consider:

*some_file_name_here*.doc

is actually:

`_some_file_name_here_.doc`

So, I have a few questions about underscore-styled italics in the future:

### 1. What are the percentage stats in using `_` vs `*` for styling italics?

### 2. Is it considered "wrong" to use a filename outside of backtics `` since file names may start/end with the italics styler `_`?

---

Four years later, I decided to always use filenames as `code` as explained in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398455/405046).

Comment: Interesting proposition. For me it feels wrong to format a filename as code. The alternative would then be to escap each underscore, which is tedious work.

Comment: @Luuklag I agree about formatting filenames as `code`, et cetera. I intentionally *do not* format my filenames as `code` as a matter of my own style consistency.

Comment: I did some testing in the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/350177#350177)  And this will not be as problematic as I initially thought. It will **only** affect filenames that start **and** end with an underscore.

Comment: I saw that, and it is good, but still... It is not "infinite". "Infinite vs usual" would be the issue.

Comment: @Robotnik Oh my! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## List of *completely* broken posts

We need a tool which detects posts which are completely broken by the change in the syntax, not just with minor formatting differences. Things like completely new/lost blocks, completely different block hieararchy etc.

With this list, we could check the most popular posts, the most frequently updated posts etc. and fix them before they're accidentally broken by a random edit.

This may also help find more incompatibilities and maybe fix them automatically.

Comment: I've outlined this in the comments on [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348937/507720): getting a sane list of all truly affected posts for public evaluation is difficult because we're dealing with a lot of tiny nuances that are detected as false positives. I don't see a good way to filter the signal from the noise yet. On the other hand, I've yet to encounter a post that I'd consider _"completely broken"_. All cases I've seen are trivial or fairly obvious when you look at the Markdown source. I'll think about a solution to your request but I can't promise anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

It seems I cannot paste images anymore. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then submit it, it loads for a while and then goes back to the text without inserting anything, and I get this error in the devtools:

```js
Uncaught Error: Markdown renderer is not initialized
    at Commonmark.Converter.makeHtml (wmd.en.js?v=65d6d3725fef:1)
    at a.y.addLinkDef (wmd.en.js?v=65d6d3725fef:2)
    at l (wmd.en.js?v=65d6d3725fef:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (wmd.en.js?v=65d6d3725fef:2)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Not sure if this is really because of the new renderer or something else that happened and it sounds weird that nobody else reported it here yet, but the error does come from `Commonmark.Converter` so I thought maybe I should post it here anyway.

EDIT: I cannot reproduce it any longer, not sure what was going on there. I had it several times in a row but now no matter what I do, it always works correctly.

Comment: Good catch, this is indeed caused by us lazy-loading the new CommonMark renderer. Looks like I missed the _"user pastes an image without entering text first"_ case :)

Comment: Actually I did enter text. I wrote one line and then pasted.

Comment: And now I cannot reproduce it (it works even without first entering text), yet before it happened several times in a row. That's weird.

Comment: Nope, no matter what I do now - answer, second answer, edit, with and without draft, starting to type before page is done loading, etc. I cannot reproduce it again :-|

Comment: Because you only need to load it one time, unless you clear your cache I guess. You could check in a different browser or an incognito browser screen.

Comment: @Luuklag it should be loaded on demand even if you haven't cached it locally. Turns out I did cover the edge case I thought I'd missed as part of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348953/image-upload-and-hyperlink-tools-fail-to-generate-markdown-until-you-type-someth/348974#348974) bug fix so I don't see why this wouldn't be working. Can't reproduce myself, so I'm gonna mark this as `norepro` for now.

Answer (score 2):

This was probably already asked somewhere in the comments, but
I couldn't find it.  I prefer to write my answers in raw (X)HTML, and
the only way to get syntax highlighting there until now were the
comments.  Will comments still work in such cases?  If not, can I write:

```xml
<pre><code class="language-c">
</code></pre>
```

Like some CommonMark adopters allow users to do?

Comment: As your answer proves (we're rendering this one with CommonMark already) it continues to work. I'm not here to tell you what to do but if your reason for using HTML over Markdown was Markdown's quirks, things might have become more reasonable now that we've switched to CommonMark and you might want to give it a try. Mixing HTML and Markdown has been and continues to be a hot take as it can result in really hard-to-predict behavior.

Comment: @HamVocke  I see, thanks.  I'll think about switching back later, but for now I'll stick to XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (by-magic)[helpcenter](/questions/tagged/helpcenter)[10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools)

The Help Center article on 10k-tools shows:

[image]

Can anyone update to the correct header?

Comment: It is fixed? auto? no[status-fixed] but has [bug]?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy it appears to have been fixed indeed.

Comment: Yep, seems from the revision history (only visible to CMs, and possibly mods?) for that page that this got fixed back in October 2020. I assume Ham Vocke just forgot to add the tag to this answer to mark it as completed :)

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Possible [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the migration tool.

In [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226878/100620), I quoted two portions of the OP's post.  Each posted as one long line, prefixed by `>` , with a blank line between the two:

```
> ... `for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:`. In this loop, it's just \$O(n)\$ where n is just number of digits of the input.

> I am assuming the time complexity of this code is something like O(n) + 2 * O(number of digits in base10) which is linear.
```

This produced two separate block quotes, like:

> ... `for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:`. In this loop, it's just $O(n)$ where n is just number of digits of the input.

> I am assuming the time complexity of this code is something like O(n) + 2 * O(number of digits in base10) which is linear.

The Common Mark migration tool added a `>`  line between these:

```
> ... `for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:`. In this loop, it's just \$O(n)\$ where n is just number of digits of the input.
>
> I am assuming the time complexity of this code is something like O(n) + 2 * O(number of digits in base10) which is linear.
```

Which resulted in one block quote, instead of two:

> ... `for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:`. In this loop, it's just $O(n)$ where n is just number of digits of the input.
>
> I am assuming the time complexity of this code is something like O(n) + 2 * O(number of digits in base10) which is linear.

The intention was to have two distinct block quotes; the rendered output differs from the original rendered output.  It isn't worth an edit to revert the appearance back to the intended, bumping the post back to "active" status.  This isn't an isolated case; [another of my answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241158/100620) was edited the same way, changing two block-quotes into one.  It will likely arise when additional sites are migrated as well.

Comment: Uh...I'm kind of missing how you actually achieved this to be two distinct blockquotes *before* the migration. The point of introducing that `>` there is that before the migration these two lines *didn't* render as two blockquotes since that wasn't possible before CommonMark, so the migration tool tries to reproduce that.

Comment: (In case you're comparing the revisions, keep in mind that the older revisions in the revision history are now rendered with the new markdown engine, too. That is, however, *not* how they actually looked like before the site was switched to CommonMark.)

Comment: @ChristianRau I may have been exploiting a bug, previously.  IIRC adding 2 spaces at the end of a block quote line (`> yada yada {space}{space}\n> yada yada`) allowed you to insert newlines in block quotes.  Without the 2 spaces, the block quote would join the lines together, wrapping at the width of the block quote box.  I probably had two spaces at the end of the first quote, the blank lines, and then started the second quote, and observed it created two separate quotes as I intended.  I'd have to test on a non-upgraded site to be sure.

Comment: Well, I'm not able to reproduce it on Stack Overflow, which hasn't been upgraded yet.  Colour me confused.  I'm confident when I posted the answers, I did something to make the quotes appear as separate block quotes, without non-quoted text appearing in between.  Adding double spaces at the end of the block quote would be a stupid hack only a few would have accidentally discovered, so it wouldn't be many posts that would be affected (that is, if it did work and I'm not going insane).  Going forward, it will be much easier to make the 2 block-quotes separate, so, yay.

Comment: I used to add HTML quotes (`<!-- -->`) to break up blog quotes.

Answer (score 1):

## Help me understand the "#" issue?

Hi tech crew, thanks, you mention:

[image]

I have many of the top answers (and questions) in iOS and Unity, on SO.

I have **never** put a space after the "#" for headlines :( ... so sorry.

What should I do?

- I should do nothing, a computer will fix it
- I should manually edit every one of my Q and A, and add a space
- I misunderstand the situation, this does not apply to SO
- I should do nothing regarding the existing corpus, but, from now on I must use the extra space
- Some other unimagined option from an undreamt of paradigm

Help!

Thx, or I should say

#thx

:O

Comment: The bot will automatically fix all the past occurrences for you, but Stack Overflow is scheduled to be fixed last across the network, so it hasn't happened yet. In the future, the space will be required and failing to include a space will result in it not being formatted as a header, but as regular text.

Comment: Basically, if you do nothing, headers formatted as `#this is a header` will be (eventually) automatically fixed to `# this is a header`. (The exception is if the system has trouble automatically converting something in the post, in which case it'll leave that post as-is for now; then, that post will continue to stay as-is unless it gets edited. If you or someone edits that post, *then* the post will be re-rendered; that's when you'd need to add the space in manually after the `#`. And you will have to include that space for *new* posts made after the switch for headers to render properly.

Comment: The correct answer is that you don't need to do anything for the existing corpus (that will be fixed automatically in so far as possible), but you should start using the extra space from now on.

Comment: All three BartvanIngenSchenau animuson V2Blast  perfect information - thanks, great stuff.  Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance this will lead to improved (safe) HTML support in the future?

In particular:

```html
<details open>
    <summary>Summary</summary>
    Details
</details>

<abbr title="title">abbr</abbr>

<mark>highlight</mark>
```

*Rendered versions below — all failing at time of posting*

---

Summary
    Details

abbr

highlight

Answer (score 1):

### Links don't work inside `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags

Samples:

<sub>This is [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).</sub>


<sub>This is [Stack Exchange][se].</sub>


<sub>This is [se].</sub>


<sub>This is https://stackexchange.com/</sub>

Comment: You need to use HTML inside them to create links. CommonMark forbids processing further Markdown within an HTML block.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but when a code block is nested with a list item and idented with 8 spaces, all the lines of the code have some extra spacing at the beginning.

Example, this markdown:

```
- Some text

        some code block
        idented by 8 spaces
```

Is rendered as:

- Some text

  ```
    some code block
    idented by 8 spaces
  ```

To help visualize the issue, that's an image of the above (with the extra space free-hand-red-circled):

[image]

---

Just to compare with a non-nested code block, note that there are less spacing at the beginning of each line:

```
some code block
idented by 4 spaces
```

---

BTW, I've found a workaround for this: align code fences with the list item. So this:

````
- Some text
  ```
  some code block
  inside nested code fences
  ```
````

Is rendered as:

- Some text

  ```
  some code block
  inside nested code fences
  ```

But it'd be nice if 8-space idented code blocks - when nested with a list item - could be rendered the same way (it was before the migration) - I had 2 answers that weren't edited by the migration so I had to fix them manually.

Comment: This works [as designed](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#list-items). You're right that the behavior changed after the migration, but I'd argue it changed for the better. In order to nest anything as part of a list item, you'll have to line things up with the first letter of your list item after bullets and spaces. For indented code blocks that means you add spaces until you've cleared the bullet character and spaces and then add 4 more spaces to denote an indented code block. Unfortunately we couldn't detect this as part of the automatic migration easily.

Comment: @HamVocke You're right, it makes much more sense now. Thanks for the reply!