# A number next to a single asterisk disables Markdown formatting (italics)

Tags: bug, markdown

When composing a post on any Stack Exchange site using Markdown, it appears that when one tries to put a number and some *italisized text* next to each other, neither asterisk ("*"), nor underscore ("_") symbols result in proper markup:

`1*A*` → 1*A*
`*A*1` → *A*1
`1_A_` → 1_A_
`_A_1` → _A_1

whereas there is no such problem for **bold text**:

`1**A**` → 1**A**
`**A**1` → **A**1

I cannot reproduce this issue with other standalone apps and services like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/app#), GitHub or, say, Joplin, so I presume this should be SE-specific.
I'm aware of several workarounds:

- HTML tags: `1<i>A</i>` → 1*A*
- Unicode U+200B ("ZERO WIDTH SPACE") symbol: `1​*A*` → 1​*A*
- MathJax: `$1\textit{A}$` → $1\textit{A}$ (appears correctly on the sites where MathJax is enabled)

but they have disadvantages.
HTML tags are awkward to use and break the workflow initiating a second markup language.
Using Unicode and MathJax would be semantically incorrect and also likely break search results.

Originally, I encountered this problem on [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) when I tried to format a compound's name with [stereocenter descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules#Assigning_descriptors), e.g. something including, say, `(1*S*,2*R*)` which renders improperly: (1*S*,2*R*).

Comment: Maybe this gets resolved when they move to CommonMark [this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/158100).

Comment: Basically it’s working as intended.