# Language hint in list breaks list in StackExchange sites but not in Meta

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, language-hints

I'm trying to add a language hint to a snippet in a list item like so:

```
- A list with code:

  <!-- language: lang-none -->

      some code

  with follow-up...
- Another item
```

In the Meta preview, it renders as expected:

[image]

Here is it live:

- A list with code:

  ```
  some code
  ```

  with follow-up...
- Another item

On StackOverflow and electronics.SE on the other hand, it breaks the list and renders as:

[image]

I posted (and deleted) [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238552/test-question-for-list-formatting-with-code-block-and-language-hint) to ensure that it was following through with the formatting, and it does indeed seem to.

Why is this happening, and is there any reliable way to add  language hint to a code block within a list?

Comment: Stack Exchange is switching to a different type of Markdown renderer, which has rolled out on Meta, but not on the other sites yet. Also, the HTML comment language hints won't work with the new renderer. For the full info, see [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta has [switched to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). Fortunately all other sites will soon switch too and then everything will

1. be consistent
2. render as you expect

Note that language codes work differently in CommonMark so do read that question for how the new syntax works.