# Strikethrough markdown not rendering on post, but works on preview

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

I just made an edit to a question on an SE site. I wanted to strikeout some of the text, so I used the ~~ wrap to do this. I could see this correctly applied in the preview.

However, after posting the update, the rendered post just shows the original text with the `~~`, and not the strikethrough effect.

**Example**:

~~this text is strikethrough in the post preview~~

**Screenshot from edit:**

[image]

Comment: This must be because of the CommonMark migration: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark?cb=1

Comment: @Luuklag Ah I didn't realise that was happening, thanks for the info. Makes sense to expect some quirks for a few weeks then.

Comment: I added it as a bug to that post for more exposure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349493/361484

Comment: @musefan for now you can use `<del></del>` html tags to create strikethrough text. Looks like the tilde syntax was never supported but they may add it in the future