# Extra line breaks appear in editor when editing a post in Microsoft Edge

Tags: bug, editor, microsoft-edge

When editing any post in Microsoft Edge (Legacy)*, a whole bunch of extra line breaks appear in the post editor.

Example:

> [image: Extra line breaks appear in editor]

The same screenshot in Chrome:

> [image: No extra line breaks]

These extra line breaks reduce the amount of the post I can read, and while these do end up collapsed when submitted, that collapsing won't happen on code blocks, which can result in posts unexpectedly breaking when edited in Edge.

Can this please be fixed?

---

* Even though there's a new Chromium-based Microsoft Edge coming, Stack Exchange [affirmed in July that they will still support the legacy version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/71208/107), and the new Highlight.js syntax highlighter being rolled out in September was also tested there. I prefer the original version for various reasons, which I won't get into here.

---

<sup>This was [originally posted as an answer to the CommonMark migration post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349589/377214) as due to the timing I thought it was related, but this turned out to be a separate, unrelated bug, and the developer responding to it [asked me to post it as a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark/349589?noredirect=1#comment1170083_349589). The answer has since been deleted, so the above links are 10k-only.</sup>

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Luuklag Edge 44, released last month.

Comment: I can also reproduce it Microsoft Edge 44. I tried editing [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809) (example) on Stack Overflow and it does show extra blank spaces. It seems it just has too many line endings or something. Not sure. For completeness' sake - I tried this with the "improve this question" as an anonymous user. 1. To check if that editor also showed the problem 2. I was being lazy and didn't want to log in.

Comment: Forgot to add screenshots: [Edge](https://i.imgur.com/jn06aLy.png) and [Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/CfULT81.png) both using the dedicated editor (non-inline) as an anonymous user.

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*