# Link renders differently on client and server side when preceded by a special character

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

When editing a question on *[History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/tour)*, I observed that a link which was not rendered in the post was hyperlinked in the edit preview (see pictures below). I tried reproducing it in the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349715/771581) to see if this also happens when the post is posted for the first time and observed the same.

It seems to be a bug after the shift to CommonMark, leading to the different rendering of links on client and server-side. A link following a special character (without any space) is not hyperlinked in the post but is hyperlinked in the preview. A link separated from the special character with a white space appears to have no such problem. (see pictures below and my [Sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349715/771581)).

## Link not hyperlinked in post

[image: Link not hyperlinked in post]

## Same link hyperlinked in preview

[image: Link hyperlinked in preview]

Comment: Ah, colons tend to confuse the preview. I reported a similar (but not the same) bug with colons adjacent to URLs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349244/377214

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog: It's not just `:`, other characters like `[` before the `https://` also seem to be a difference between editor vs. render.  [Editor preview shows links clickable, final rendered post doesn't, when surrounded by \[\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351191) turned out to be a duplicate of this.

Comment: As well as other special characters like `; % - # &`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for highlighting this.

We're using different renderers for the preview and for rendering Markdown content server-side and both use their own, built-in mechanism to detect links. Ideally, both would behave exactly the same. Unfortunately they don't quite match perfectly all the time.

I've got a bugfix about to go out that's trying to make both renderers behave more alike. We won't attempt to make both behave exactly equivalent and there will always be edge cases where the preview is showing something slightly different from the server-side rendered post. I know this can be annoying at times. However, the effort it'd take to get this perfect outweighs the benefit in my view, especially given that the workaround is simple: Add a space after interpunction characters (as you should do for proper interpunction anyway, in my humble opinion) or use proper Markdown link syntax to denote your hyperlinks. On top of that, I want to avoid introducing bugs where something gets incorrectly auto-linked.

With the bugfix in place, a URL appearing right after a colon `:`, a semicolon `;`, a hash `#` without any space will be rendered as a hyperlink in the preview and on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the update Ham. I wonder why it would be hard to have the same renderer on two places. Isn't it simply copy paste?

Comment: @Luuklag unfortunately it isn't. In the preview, we're using [linkify-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/linkify-it) which comes bundled with [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it). It's all written in JavaScript and based on regular expressions. On the server, we're using [markdig's](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig) AutoLink extension. This one's using a quite different approach altogether. Auto-detecting links is more complicated than it seems on the surface, that's why I'd prefer to leave link detection to those libraries as much as we can.

Comment: Why don't you use Node to run the same Javascript code on the server and client?

Comment: Note I reported also [<s>links</s> are autocompleted on preview but not rendered when posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351092/209901). It was marked as dupe of this, while this answer is not solving that case because the exception has been made for colon, semicolon and hash.