# Discrepancies in CommonMark rendering

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

One of the users on Stack Overflow pointed out that the rendered version of some posts is not what the preview or revision shows. After triggering a re-render the glitch was gone, but since it is not a problem to find more I found another one.

Here is an example of the difference.

[Force celery to use json in place of pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919065/force-celery-to-use-json-in-place-of-pickle)

> [image]

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36919065/revisions

> [image]

However, I noticed that there are more differences in the rendered version and the one generated by CommonMark which is the reason that I am raising this as a bug, so the developers can take a look at it if they are not aware of it yet.

#### Inline code not generated properly when following HTML

The rendered version of [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005151/1839439) is correct:

> [image]

But the preview is broken:

> [image]

Also:

- [Apache: Redirect some files in directory, "not found" others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23876089/1839439)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747034/1839439
- [convert oracle varchar date read into variable to linux date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24059668/1839439)
- [Flex Embedding Roboto Font - Transcoding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9798770/1839439)

But not here:

- [Linux command within Javascript or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1183573/1839439)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031177/1839439

#### Ignoring HTML code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677038/1839439

Before:

> [image]

After:

> [image]

#### Not even sure what is going on here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345365/1839439

Before:

> [image]

After:

> [image]

Other posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46681764/1839439
- [How to run spring batch job multiple times with different job parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31313826/1839439)
- ['Input string not in correct format' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8559109/1839439)

Comment: Links also have such [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581).

Comment: One more issue in the preview: [inside code blocks, space characters in an all-space row are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350313/419414) (they should be intact)

Answer (score 4):

> However, I noticed that there are more differences in the rendered version and the one generated by CommonMark which is the reason that I am raising this as a bug, so the developers can take a look at it if they are not aware of it yet.

All those are expected:

> We avoid breaking existing posts by erring on the side of safety. If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) **we won’t automatically re-render the post and put it up for investigation first**. This way we can be sure that all changes are safe.
>
> [...]
>
> There will be some changes caused by the new Markdown renderer that we need to investigate because they will cause posts to look different than before in one way or another. We can’t foresee all edge cases that this change will introduce so we will surface **all posts that look different when rendered with the new Markdown renderer, review them and if necessary fix them.**

In "bucket" number 2 (aka improvements), where the previous rendering was wrong:

- [Force celery to use json in place of pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919065/force-celery-to-use-json-in-place-of-pickle)

On those cases forcing a re-rendering by editing the post would correct the rendered version.

Now, the rest, the users mixed html and markdown. If you see the revisions, I basically removed the html tags and everything looked like it should, then I improved the formatting. With this I investigated the issue and fixed the problem: it was between the chair and the keyboard.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005151/1839439
- [Redirect some files in directory, "not found" others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23876089/792066)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747034/792066
- [convert oracle varchar date read into variable to linux date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24059668/792066)
- [Flex Embedding Roboto Font - Transcoding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9798770/792066)
- [Linux command within Javascript or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1183573/792066)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031177/792066
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677038/792066
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345365/792066
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005151/792066