# Markdown inconsistency between preview and post when using blank lines

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, markdown-preview

This happened in [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206692/78410) on [Code Golf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), where we have all sorts of uncommon programming languages to put in a code block.

OP's code is copied here at the markdown level:

```
bbcccbc-cc-b--b-- c
b
   
c
 -
L`.{6}
.
$0X 
Y`X`\LAPACK
.L
L
```

The above uses raw `<pre><code>` to preserve the blank-only line (by ending with `&#32;`) between the line with single `b` and the one with single `c` (check it by dragging on it). But it is wrong because the code should start with a single empty line, not two; removing a line there will break the entire code block.

On the other hand, using the fenced or indented block <s>does not have any way to preserve the blank-only line (it is stripped now, but it should be preserved in order to be a valid code)</s> works as expected with the blank-only lines, but is not shown as such in the preview section.

Using fenced block:

```
bbcccbc-cc-b--b-- c
b
   
c
 -
L`.{6}
.
$0X 
Y`X`\LAPACK
.L
L
```

Using indented block:

```
bbcccbc-cc-b--b-- c
b
   
c
 -
L`.{6}
.
$0X 
Y`X`\LAPACK
.L
L
```

**Edit:** I just found that the three blanks *are* preserved on the main post. I saw the bug described above in the preview section, and wrongly assumed that it will be the same when actually posted. It is very likely a bug in the preview renderer.