# Inconsistent Markdown rendering between preview and final post

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

When I attempted to edit [this revision](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/revisions/37025/3) of a post, I noticed that the preview is different from how the post appears:

Preview rendering:

---

[image: Preview rendering]

---

Post rendering:

---

[image: Post rendering]

---

Markup:

---

[image]

---

The actual URLs of the links are also different. At most one of these renderings can be correct.

---

Reproduction attempt: Click "edit" on this question to see the different rendering in the preview:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates%5B2%5D)

Comment: I comfirm I can repeat this using the "reproduction attempt" as give above.

Comment: Links appear to have some problem. See this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581).