# Editor preview shows links clickable, final rendered post doesn't, when surrounded by []

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, markdown-preview

[https://example.com/] appears as a clickable link in the preview, but not in the final render when saved.

This applies to at least the inline editor (tested on Stack Overflow) and question-ask page here.

---

Probably related bug: *[Inconsistent Markdown rendering between preview and final post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351027/inconsistent-markdown-rendering-between-preview-and-final-post)* also from after the change to CommonMark.

(Discovered on Stack Overflow; presumably the URLs in *https://stackoverflow.com/posts/93132/revisions* were clickable before the CommonMark changeover, but they aren't now. A recent suggested-edit changed a URL, but left them non-clickable, which I found surprising.  For the current version I simply removed the `[]` around the URLs.)

Comment: Links have some problem: [CommonMark: Link rendering differently on client and server sides](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581)

Comment: @GarimanSingh: Ah, that might be an exact duplicate: a non-space character before the `https://` stopped the server-side renderer from noticing it as a URL.

Comment: The problem seems specific to special characters only, not any non-whitespace character. I tested it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349715/771581).