# Missed commonmark migration target: tag wiki uses the same engine too!

Tags: feature-request, markdown

With [the migration of the render to CommonMark,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/) tag wiki were not included in the checks and tweak for the new render. This leaves potential issues with headings and lists that are rendered incorrectly in the tag wiki. Please do a pass over these post too so that the migration is trully complete.

Comment: This was noted in the main CommonMark migration thread too (with a dev response): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349385/313042