# Bad Markdown rendering (but not preview) when using «guillemets»

Tags: bug, markdown

What I did (and what the preview showed correctly):

```
Similaj vortoj ekzistas en la germana («*[die] Rektion*»), la nederlanda
(«*[de] rectie*»), kaj eĉ la suoma («*rektio*»).
```

What I got:

[image: Screenshot of the incorrect rendering. The starting asterisk is shown and instead of the text between the first and second asterisk being italics, the text between the second and third asterisk is italicised. The italicisation is similarly wrong between the fourth and fifth asterisk as well. The sixth asterisk is shown again.]

> Similaj vortoj ekzistas en la germana («*[die] Rektion*»), la nederlanda
> («*[de] rectie*»), kaj eĉ la suoma («*rektio*»).

Only the text in the guillemets should be italic, but it's broken.  The
text is from
[my answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5998/2092) on the
Esperanto StackExchange site.  I fixed it there using raw HTML.

As far as I know, StackExchange-network-wide bugs, including those of
rendering, should be reported here.

Comment: Well you only use astrixes on the beginning and end, so why shouldn't everything be in italics?

Comment: @Luuklag There are three pairs of asterisks. However instead of three italicised sections between 1-2, 3-4, and 5-6, it produces *two* italicised sections between 2-3 and 4-5 leaving asterisk 1 and 6 plain and not counting them as the start/end of an italics section.

Comment: @VLAZ oh yes ofcourse. Probably some white spacig around the asterixes would solve this.

Answer (score 3):

The quick work around would be to add a space between the guillemets and the asterisk, like this:

```
Similaj vortoj ekzistas en la germana (« *[die] Rektion* »), la nederlanda
(« *[de] rectie* »), kaj eĉ la suoma (« *rektio* »).
```

Which renders the correctly italised text:

Similaj vortoj ekzistas en la germana (« *[die] Rektion* »), la nederlanda
(« *[de] rectie* »), kaj eĉ la suoma (« *rektio* »).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already used a different workaround (raw HTML).  Besides, spacing of quotes depends on the language and the style-guide (e.g. French uses spaces inside guillemets, but Russian doesn't), so this workaround may not be acceptable in some cases.