# How can I list all my questions and answers whose CommonMark rendering doesn't match the cached rendering?

Tags: support, questions, answers, markdown

I understand that [the CommonMark migration messes up the formatting of some answers and posts once they're edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354062/178179).

How can I list all my questions and answers whose CommonMark rendering doesn't match the cached rendering?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but... maybe you can search SEDE for any posts that weren't edited by Community during the period of time when those edits were being made?

Comment: @Catija That can mean two things, however: either they weren't edited because the automated script didn't contain a rule for them and so couldn't edit it to be compliant, or there was no need to edit them because it would be compliant with both renderers anyway (e.g. a simple paragraph of text with no formatting). It would be nice to filter those results to just the first category.

Comment: It is strange to be so focused on an implementation detail that can only be answered if a Post is newly rendered and then check if  its result differs from what is currently on offer. If you have rendered it you might as well store it, which defeats the whole point of not re-rendering all posts. Obviously posts with blockquotes have become more strict. Specially where blockquotes are have a blank line (if I understand the problem correctly) so let's try to find those posts. How about this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1293847