# How can I find my posts where the headers are now busted after the migration to CommonMark

Tags: support, data-explorer, commonmark

CommonMark is a bit more strict than the previous markdown flavor.

One of these cases is the markdown for headers to generate an H1, H2 or H3. A `#` on a new line followed by text was all that was needed, for example:

```
###Header3
```

There was no requirement that the # needed to be followed by a space. With the switch to CommonMark this has changed and a space is mandatory.

I was a notorious no-space user.

Is there a SEDE query that can show me the posts where I most likely used header markup that is now rendered incorrectly?

Comment: A bit more general question, but with no answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354142/how-can-i-list-all-my-questions-and-answers-whose-commonmark-rendering-doesnt-m

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog yeah, I have given up on answering that. My attempt is in my deleted answer there ...

Comment: I believe, that fixing spaces after # should not be responsibility of individual users, but should be fixed by conversion utility. See my feature request https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363196/lines-starting-with-a-hash-without-spaces-before-the-words-stopped-to-be-recogni?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can inspect the Body of the Posts table. You'll find the following html content in that field for a broken header:

```html
<p>###Header3
Lorum ipsum
</p>
```

There is a new line (char(10)) after the header.

With this knowledge [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1379466?UserId=811) returns your most likely broken posts:

```sql
select id as [Post Link]  
from posts
where owneruserid = ##userid?811##
and (
body like concat('%', nchar(10), '<p>###[^ ]%' , nchar(10), '%')
or body like concat('%', nchar(10), '<p>##[^ ]%' , nchar(10), '%')
or body like concat('%', nchar(10), '<p>#[^ ]%' , nchar(10), '%')
)
```

Due to the naïve way of parsing you might have some false positives.

I leave it to others to maybe reduce the false positive rate by inspecting the actual markdown the PostHistory table.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).