# Why was "Commonmark migration" notice suppressed here -- and not everywhere?

Tags: discussion, community-user, commonmark

I noticed in [an old answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/74271/14897) an edit I made over a year ago. When I checked the revision history, I realized Community ◆ should have left its *Commonmark migration* note in a newer revision. But that did not happen.

So, *out of curiosity,* why did Community ◆ not leave a note, even though the markdown render is the new type despite the old markdown I used, and by extension -- why wasn't it suppressed everywhere? You know, instead of...

> [image] :D

Example for same style where there was a record: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/29389/revisions

---

In case something changes, here are screenshots:

> [image]

Comment: Some posts are only rerendered upon editing, and it's bumpless (`"However, once someone comes in and edits it, it will be ..."`): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/282094 (does *that* answer your question?), see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258587/282094

Comment: @Rob: see link I added please, thx

Comment: @Rob: I'm *really* sorry, but I'm super confused. The one where the last revision is mine was *before* the rollout of the new CommonMark, so where is Community's revision?

Comment: ymb1, so I'll stick with my first comment; which corresponds with the chosen answer. 

Comment: I've elaborated on this at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354065/377214

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer was simply left alone and has not been re-rendered on the new Markdown system yet. If you attempt to edit it, the formatting will break because it does not use correct syntax for blockquotes.

Not all posts were edited during the migration. Some were skipped because of issues that made it hard or impossible to update the post because we couldn't determine what the intention was or attempting to fix it automatically would break the post further. So their old rendering was left there until someone manually edits and fixes it. This was also explained in the announcement for the migration.