# Markdown doesn't ignore colon in the end of bare URL address

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, hyperlinks

If a hyperlink is followed by a colon, the colon is treated as a part of the hyperlink.

**An example:**

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact:*

> *If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta. (Look under "help" on the top bar.)*

As a result the hyperlink is broken, it then leads to a 404 page.

This is inconsistent with prior behavior, which treated the colon as *not* being part of the link, and as such breaks existing posts with colons after links which depended on the colon not being part of the link.

Comment: The usual workarounds include putting the link in angle brackets, e.g. `<https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact>:`, or making a proper link with link text, e.g. `[contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact):`.

Comment: Anything you place at the end of a bare URL is being treated as part of the URL, ***except*** for the **space** character. EG: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact123` https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact123 - doesn't work even though  isn't a valid character for an URL. --- Whereas, https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact 123 is OK (note added space character). --- In comments it's OK, in the editor it's broken.

Comment: Are we sure this is a bug? This may be working as intended. Colons can be part of a URL, right?

Comment: @Mast In the past, colons at the end of a bare URL link used to *not* be treated as part of the URL, so this breaks links in posts that depended on the prior behavior.

Comment: @Mast it's a special case of "breaking changes" done by moving to a proper parser. It's almost impossible to have full backwards compatibility. So it's technically not a bug, but still since it breaks existing posts, better be fixed somehow, e.g. automated job that will fix the colons.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Yea, I figured as much [months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1167191_348746).

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask it wont break them untill they are edited. At which point the editor should notice.

Comment: @Luuklag And hopefully the editor won't leave bare links around at all. They look bad. :D

Comment: Works fine for [your](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355723/markdown-doesnt-ignore-colon-in-the-end-of-bare-url-address:) question URL.

Comment: @Ollie not relevant, you can [put anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355723/Ollie-and-the-monkeys-in-Tavern) after the question ID, it's ignored on the server. The problem is with links that don't lead to questions. ;)

Comment: @Luuklag good point, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Questions only get re-rendered when they are edited, otherwose the rendered version is stored in the DB, @ShadowWizardWearingMask

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask What about the link to [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/798831/ollie:), then?  Doesn't scream 404 at me.

Comment: @Ollie same as questions, it [doesn't matter what you put after the user ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/798831/Ollie-In-Tavern). The problem is with links that don't lead to questions or users. ;)