# CommonMark regression: image embed exclamation sign syntax broken after <p> tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images, commonmark

I ran into a regression change in the post formatting engine [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/222298).

If you try to embed an image using the exclamation sign syntax ![foo][bar] and the paragraph starts with a <p> or <hr> tag, the image formatting code is shown as literal text, not as an image.

Example:

This image is in a bare paragraph and shows up: [image: (a hand-drawn red circle as a test image)]

This image is after a <p> tag and doesn't show up: ![(a hand-drawn red circle as a test image)][1]

As a possible workaround, you can use an <img> tag: [image: a hand-drawn red circle as a test image]

I found this when I was writing [an edit to a post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/140824).  The image embedded in the post [used to show up in the cached HTML version of that post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170312100632/https://mathoverflow.net/posts/184693/revisions), but [didn't show up after a null edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/184693/2).  This confused me thoroughly, because I was trying to edit a part of the post other than the image.

Apparently [LSpice ran into the same issue and posted about it in MathOverflow Meta in 2020-07](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4632/why-dont-images-show-up-in-a-post/4633#4633), but it doesn't seem to be mentioned on Meta SE yet.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the Commonmark migration. This was a problem before (I've built some code into my Broken Image Repairer precisely to tackle this issue).

Comment: (What I meant [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4632/70594) was that the Commonmark migration caused a re-rendering of the source markdown. It's not switching dialects which caused the problem.)

Comment: I think, though I don't have a specific source on-hand, that mixing html and markdown syntax is more of a "at your own peril" thing than a suggested usage and supported feature, largely for reasons like this. They don't always play nice together.

Comment: @zcoop98 That sounds nice, and I'd be happy to write only HTML formatting everywhere. But there are kinds of formatting that SE doesn't seem to allow me to enter as HTML, such as spoiler blocks, so I must mix the two.  (Admittedly the situation is much better than in chat and comments, where you can't even write hyperlinks as HTML.)

Comment: I mean to imply the opposite- that all of markdown (~ish) is supported, but only [a very narrow subset of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/776523) is supported. The guidance is most certainly to use more Markdown than HTML, and not vice-versa.

Comment: @zcoop98 Right, but Markdown is terrible.  Nested structures are often hard or impossible to write.  I with the formatting engine allowed some way to input any kind of formatting as HTML if it's already allowed in Markdown.

Comment: wow I feel dumb, for a second I thought the circle was drawn around a blank image that was embedded when I realized that the circle is an image  .

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be working as intended. The second paragraph, where you use `<p>` to start the paragraph, does not support further Markdown. If you use HTML blocks, we do not parse *any* Markdown within them and you can only format things with more HTML.

For example, other Markdown features will not work either:

> Some text in *italics*

---

The problem you are identifying on Math Overflow appears to be specific to an `<hr>` that is being used without proper spacing between a following paragraph. Based on the rules of CommonMark, that entire block should be interpreted as a single line of text:

```
I convinced myself that there were no L-shaped examples. Then I used Google and [found one][1] with scaling by $\sqrt{\varphi}$ for $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$: <hr /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ![LL][2] <hr />
```

That makes little sense, because there are two HTML elements mixed in with Markdown. The `/` means nothing to the Markdown processor, and it is simply assuming that the image is a part of an HTML block because it is not written correctly. It has since been rewritten to have a blank line between the horizontal rule and the image, which is necessary for correct rendering.

Using the same italics example:

> ---
>
> Some text in *italics*

versus:

> ---
>
> Some text in *italics*

That the first example worked correctly in previous versions of Markdown was merely a fluke. It shouldn't have, and the way it works now is correct. An `<hr>` should be separated by blank lines on both sides.