# Markdown stopped working inside of <sub> and <sup> tags!

Tags: bug, markdown

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), at the bottom there's a section wrapped in `<sub>` `</sub>` (see screenshot below).

As you can see, markdown no longer works in it: the links are not rendered correctly, and wrapping the text in `_` didn't make it italic.

According to the [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210104120250/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), the post has looked correctly at Jan 4.

[image: a screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the [switch to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) that took place in June 2020.

As the answer to [a related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357552/commonmark-regression-image-embed-exclamation-sign-syntax-broken-after-p-tag) says:

> If you use HTML blocks, we do not parse any Markdown within them and you can only format things with more HTML.

This is just how CommonMark works, for good and for bad. I've fixed the post on Stack Overflow by replacing the `_` with `<i>`, and links with the HTML links `<a href="https://www.example.com">Example</a>` format. (The old, broken, format is still available in the revisions.)

---

Worth to mention something not directly related: how come the post was fine in January 2021, while the switch went live half year before that? The answer is that the switch did not change existing posts, only the way the posts are saved to the database when being added or edited. So the post kept its formatting, until edit occurred in the 18<sup>th</sup> to January, 2021:

[image: edit in January 18th 2021]

Which then caused the new way of rendering to save the broken format.

Comment: I assume you didn't leave the link to the Lounge untouched as a "bad" example? I mean, maybe that room count as a bad example but leaving then unlinked as punishment  is a bit rude, don't you think ;) ...  I replaced that link with html markup as well

Comment: @rene lol! Nah, just missed it. ;-)

Comment: Re *"for good and for bad."*: Don't you mean *"[for better or worse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_better_or_worse#Prepositional_phrase)"*?

Comment: @P.Mort yes, probably. Thanks!