# Markdown rendering: Trailing backslash for line break is incorrectly included in URLs but works in preview

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

I have found a bug with the Markdown renderer which causes a difference between what the preview shows and how it is being rendered after posting. The issue appears when attempting to use a forced line break using a trailing backslash (`\`), if the backslash appears *after* an URL.

For example, this code produces the problem:

```
Foo http://example.com/test.\
Bar
```

In the preview, this is rendered correctly. There is a line break (`<br>`) after the first line and the “Bar” appears in the second line. However, after saving the post, the post renderer will include both the dot and the backslash in the hyperlink causing the link to be `http://example.com/test.\` instead of just `http://example.com/test`. This appears to only happen when there is a path segment in the URL (i.e. not for `http://example.com.\`).

---

Here is a screenshot how the preview is rendered, using a quotation block for visualization (though the error is caused regardless of whether a quotation block is used or not):

[image: Rendering in preview]

And this is how it is then rendered after posting:

[image: Incorrect rendering after posting]

I’ve noticed this on Stack Overflow, but reproduced it in the [Markdown sandbox here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359063/141542). Rendered with the commonmark.js, it works correctly as you can see [in this example](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=Foo%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest.%5C%0ABar).

Comment: @Rob Since we’re [now using CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/141542), things should work according to the CommonMark spec. And there, [a trailing backslash is a valid way to produce a hard line break](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#example-631). As you can see from my examples, it also does work correctly here on SE. It’s just when combined with the URL parsing that it breaks.