# Markdown list rendering mismatch between preview and actual post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

I was browsing a Stack Overflow question and in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384101/916225) there is an ordered list, but it was written using `)` instead of `.` so I tried to edit it.

When in click edit the list was rendered correctly as ordered list without any change, but in the original post it's not rendered as ordered list.

[Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywRRC.jpg)

Comment: Since the CommonMark migration in 2020, parentheses-style lists were allowed in addition to dot-style lists; and posts need to be re-rendered in order for Markdown to be parsed and displayed as HTML. The CommonMark migration script didn’t migrate posts where the re-rendered post looked differently from the original and it wasn’t easy to fix automatically. This post wasn’t edited since 2013. See [this answer on “We're switching to CommonMark”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348753/289905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old days the only valid markdown to create a numbered list was:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

or

```
1.
1.
1.
```

In June of 2020 the Stack Exchange network [migrated to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark), of which the Stack Overflow founder [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1) is one of the contributors.

The CommonMark spec defines an [ordered list](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#list-items) as:

> a sequence of 1–9 arabic digits (`0-9`), followed by either a `.` character or a `)` character.

According to that, the way the post you cite was written is CommonMark compliant. Seeing that it was last edited in 2013 however means that it hasn't be re-rendered using the new CommonMark renderer. The vast majority of posts was re-rendered when the migration took place using migration scripts.

From the migration announcement:

> With the auto-fixing utility we estimate that we’re going to land at over 96% of all network posts being rendered completely identical after migrating to CommonMark and using the new renderers. This leaves us with a few percents of posts that end up looking differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderers.

> We avoid breaking existing posts by erring on the side of safety. If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) we won’t automatically re-render the post

As re-rendering this post resulted in different HTML (a numbered list where there previously was no list) it was left in its old state. (SE stores rendered versions of a post, rather then the markdown version).

Now trying to edit this post it will get rendered with the new renderer, according to the CommonMark spec, and will thus include a numbered list.

This was also pointed out in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark/348753#348753) to the original migration announcement, with comments from developer [Ham Vocke♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/507720) explaining things.