# Is lang-bash syntax highlighting not working anymore?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I have used `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` in one of my questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1342478/426176), but the syntax highlighting does not seem to work anymore.

EDIT 0: I changed it to `<!-- language: lang-bash -->` in one of my questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1342478/426176), but it does not work either.

EDIT 1: Nick found out there was nothing highlightable in my question.
In the past, a list of Bash commands and outputs would get highlighted but not anymore. I guess only code snippets are highlighted now.

Has the Stack Exchange syntax changed?

Comment: In this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/908360 search for the string: "code block highlighting". Your answer is probably there.

Comment: According to the bash tag it uses `lang-bsh` not `lang-bash`: *"Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-bsh"*. (and on SO it uses `lang-sh`)

Comment: @Levente Apparently it was only `language` that was deprecated, not `language-all`: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1166971_348754  (I initially got these the wrong way around hence OPs edit)

Comment: @Nick [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/373113) says `lang-bash, lang-sh, lang-zsh` work. Has it changed since ?

Comment: @Nick I've used both `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` and `<!-- language: lang-bash -->` but none of them work.

Comment: Use instead "**fenced code blocks**", opened by: `\```bash` or `\```sh`

Comment: @Nick And `<!-- language-all: lang-bsh -->` does not work either.

Comment: After some testing... It _IS_ syntax highlighted with *"<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->"*... you just _have nothing highlightable_, try put an `if` of some sort in your code block and you'll see it hightlights fine

Comment: @Nick OK I see. In the past, a list of bash commands and outputs would get highlighted but not anymore. I guess only code snippets are highlighted now.

Comment: @SebMa Then it's a valid question which needs a canonical answer.