# How is the single line spacing in this post possible?

Tags: discussion

I came across a [GIS Stack Exchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34796/115) to [Is ArcMap 10.0 Query Layer passing invalid SQL to Oracle 11gR2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34789) that uses single line spacing:

**Excerpt:**

*(Copy/pasted into this post; I couldn't format it as a quote, since the line spacing would be lost.)*

"I have been all up and down this block.
Several years ago I had a similar problem with the difference between the esri state plane crs and the same in oracle sdo.
It came down to converting my sdo ordinate array into JUST points.
I had a bud at oracle that wrote me a little function to do it for me.
I am not at that job anymore but might still have a copy. I'll take a look.
I can't remember much abou the problem but here is a later thread that has some hints in it.
[OTN spatial forum thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34796/62572)
I may have posted it to OTN spatial forum. You might search there.
If I find it I will post back here."

---

I don't think anyone would suggest that formatting is proper or helpful.

But I *am* curious, how is that single line spacing possible? Did the author use some sort of unusual line break?

Comment: It's possible using the <br> html tag or adding a double space at the end of each line. It's also mentioned in the [Help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks).

Comment: The [newer version of Markdown in use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) supports the far superior trailing backslash (\\). Significant trailing space was a grave design mistake in the original Markdown.