# Links in comments delimited by less-than/greater-than signs occasionally include the delimiting greater-than sign

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

Over at Stack Overflow, I wrote a comment that renders like this:

[image]

and links to `https://wg21.link/p2128>`, which returns 404.

The way I wrote the link in the markup is `<https://wg21.link/p2128>`; this is supported by CommonMark and in fact recommended by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-C).  It seems to work fine everywhere else on the network, and I would expect the subset of Markdown available in comments to support this.

The bug does not appear consistently; [another of my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73583448/using-ratchet-websockets-in-a-secure-environment-is-not-working/73643730#comment130129729_73643730), also using less-than/greater-than signs to delimit a link, renders okay.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Note that [comments doesn't use CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348747/241919), it's using SE's own ["watered-down comments Markdown system"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: The workaround is to not use a naked link. For example, with the link text *"unnecessary as of C++23"*.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum That would defeat the point. I often use comments for quick-and-dirty notes where I don’t want to spend too much effort on formatting by placing two different kinds of brackets, and on thinking which actual sub-phrase should constitute the link. Using ‘ASCII angle brackets’ allows me to just paste the link, while keeping link boundaries clearly delineated.