# Loading the Community user's "All actions" subtab here on Meta.SE leads to a server error

Tags: bug, meta, community-user, 500-server-error, activity

Trying to access [the Community user's list of actions here](/users/-1/community?tab=activity) results in the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" server error page. I get to this link by going to its [user profile](/users/-1), going to the Activity tab, and clicking "All actions" in the left subtab bar.

Manipulating the URL using `&sort=` to access specific activity filtering types allows the page to load normally and shows the list for most filtering types, including the [accepts](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts), [posts](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=posts), [badges](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=badges), [comments](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=comments), [reviews](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and [suggestions](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) types, but *not* for the [revisions](/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions) filtering type. Accessing that page directly using the link in this paragraph leads to the same server error page, and attempting to access it by loading a different filter link above and changing filters results in the filter not actually changing and a 500 error showing in the developer console.

A similar thing [previously occurred on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377547/accessing-communitys-profile-all-actions-tab-timeout). The cause there was that the page was timing out when loading in the revisions as there were too many revisions attributed to the Community user as a result of all the rewrite scripts that had previously occurred (the move from HTTP to HTTPS links especially). The page was fixed by reattributing those edits from Community to a nonexistent user called "URL Rewriter Bot". If that's the cause for this site, can that same thing be done to fix the error? If not, can the cause please be tracked down and fixed?

Comment: No repro, all of Communitiy's tabs are working for me.

Comment: I've reproduced. This also happens for the [network profile activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) for it. The timeout duration is much longer, though.

Comment: It's probably an intermittent error, so maybe the page is so close to the timeout that sometimes it can be served fast enough. I repro'd every time though.

Comment: @Laurel Or it could be regional. Not once was I able to load it either.

Comment: The culprit is revisions, going [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions) gives internal error. People can't see it because when loaded via AJAX it's just ignored. @bad_coder if you go to that URL, what do you get?

Comment: @bad_coder also, if you are the one who voted to close please retract and do not use this close reason for bugs you can't reproduce yourself. That is not our role but rather SE staff, who can mark such bugs with [tag:status-norepro]. The close reason clearly says when it should be used, when **changes in the system** renders the bug/request non relevant. That's very clearly not the case here.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yep, I mention this in the second paragraph.

Comment: On SO it doesn't crash with error, but loading the "Activity" initial tab took two minutes. I was sure it would time out with error, but it just took that long to load the page. Gone are the days of super fast page loads. ;)

Comment: FWIW, there is a lot of data assigned to the Community User, so the SQL query behind that All Activity page trembles at the verge of timeout. It you hammer on it (and thus the database server) it'll probably eventually load once all the data is read from disk into memory, getting a little further each time. IMHO, There are several tabs that should be disabled for that user, because browsing the data would require special infrastructure/caching

Comment: @AMtwo Yep, the "All" tab was removed for that exact reason.