# Enhancement Request: Attribution Block Markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, copyright, attribution

Over at Worldbuilding we constantly bring images and quotes in from outside sources. I suspect other Stacks do that a lot, too. When it comes to images, charts, and graphs, we want people to properly attribute the graphic. It's not just a courtesy to the creators of the graphic (who certainly deserve every ounce of credit), it's also an effort to protect their legal copyright as the graphics may not be sourced under the same copyright conditions that Stack Exchange uses.

**Request:** What I'd like to request is a means of specifically identifying a block of text as an attribution. I don't know that it needs to go so far as to be programmatically attached to the graphic, although that would be nice. I imagine something like the single-asterisk list block or the close-angle-bracket quotation block. Not only would this provide uniform formatting for attributions, but it would also allow text readers to properly identify the purpose of the block and, hopefully, would encourage more people to include attributions.

Comment: In HTML, I guess the most appropriate markup would be `<figure>[quote or picture]<figcaption>attribution</figcaption></figure>`. But it seems Stack Exchange Markdown filters that out.

Comment: @user3840170 Yup, but that's exactly what I'm looking for... other than a nice one-character solution like ">" for quotes would be convenient, or perhaps a delimited field on the image reference. E.G., `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTXr.jpg~ attribution`

Comment: On first sight, this even seems to be supported by the [Markdig library](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) which is [used by SE nowadays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark), but they would need to enable the respective extension: https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig.Tests/Specs/FigureFooterAndCiteSpecs.md#figures

Comment: @JBH FYI, tooltips are supported for images and links: `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTXr.jpg "tooltip"`

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That's helpful, but not an appropriate solution to the problem. Attribution is expected (in a legal context) to be obvious and easy to find, as well as presented to the user when using any disability settings like text readers, which should state that the attribution is an attribution. The tooltip solution requires a mouse roll-over just to see it (non-intuitive) and likely wouldn't be read out by a text reader on the first pass through the text (but I could be wrong about that).